# Em C++ onde as funções dos objetos estão na memória?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, funções, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Em C++ quando um objeto é declarado, as variáveis da classe são guardadas no *stack* ou no *heap* dependendo de como o objeto foi criado. Com o operador `sizeof()` é possível testar e perceber que o tamanho do objeto de uma classe é alocado de acordo com as variáveis que ela contém, não sendo reservado nenhum espaço para as funções junto ao objeto.

Isso levanta várias questões.

- Onde as funções que são declaradas dentro de uma classe estão na memória?
- Se não existir nenhuma instância da classe, ainda sim a função existe?
- Se existirem mais de uma instância da classe, existe mais de uma cópia do código da função na memória?
- Se eu tiver um ponteiro para uma função de uma classe e mudar o byte de uma instrução, o método será estragado em todas as instâncias?

Comment: Note que qualquer resposta vai ser específica para certos compiladores e não para C++ como um todo. O padrão C++ não requer, por exemplo, a separação entre pilha e _heap_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- As funções normalmente estão em uma área chamada de estática.
- O espaço ocupado pelo código binário das funções está lá independentemente de haver instância ou não, até porque a instanciação nada tem a ver com os códigos. No fundo funções são mais independentes do que as pessoas imaginam.
- Assim como as funções só ocupam espaço uma vez, e não por cada instância criada. A função (seu código) é global. Se pensar no código como um dado, não tem razão para existir mais de uma cópia dele. Mesmo que ele seja executado várias vezes, em situações diferentes, o código em si só precisa existir uma vez.
- Se mudar o código (se puder fazer isso) será mudado para todas as instâncias, afinal só existe uma função para todas.

É importante notar que o espaço ocupado na memória é relativo. Pode ser que ocupe nada na memória RAM. O código geralmente é carregado por mapeamento de arquivo em memória e o sistema operacional carrega efetivamente pra memória apenas as páginas que vão sendo usadas. Portanto uma função nunca chamada tem boa chance de nunca entrar na memória RAM. Ocupará, claro, um espaço no endereçamento virtual, mas isso já é [outro assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/101).

É claro que se não houver instâncias de uma classe, há uma possibilidade, por otimização, do compilador/*linkeditor* não incluir código algum no executável da aplicação.

Mas mesmo outros códigos que nunca passaram perto do seu código podem ser incluídos juntos por estarem juntos com códigos que seu código usou efetivamente. Os códigos estão em unidades de compilação indissociáveis. Se usar uma função de uma unidade de compilação, vai tudo o que estiver nessa unidade. É comum que a unidade tenha só a classe específica ou outras que possuem total dependência dela (já otimizações que são mais granulares, mas isso ainda não é tão comum).

É bom entender que não existem funções de instância de fato. Tudo é função normal. O que diferencia ser de instância é a função ter um primeiro parâmetro (geralmente oculto) chamado `this` que é um ponteiro para a instância propriamente dita. Também não entrarei em detalhes aqui, não é o foco.

A maneira exata como tudo isso procederá pode variar em cada implementação do compilador e poderá ser melhor adaptado para cada sistema operacional. Mas nenhum que eu conheça inventou algo muito inovador.

Considere que é possível existir uma aplicação que permita injeção de código em tempo de execução, que permita compilação Just-in-Time, ou outros malabarismos que modifiquem um pouco esta ideia (não muito), mas nenhum desses artifícios são comuns em C++.

Lembre-se que essas áreas de memória faladas são conceitos abstratos. Não existe nada que demarque fisicamente cada parte. No fundo a área estática não é muito diferente das demais. Em geral ela fica um pouco mais protegida pelo sistema operacional contra alterações, conforme indicação do *runtime* da linguagem.

Existem espaços ocupados que muitos não enxergam. Há [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) na alocação dos objetos, além do seu próprio tamanho, há dados dos tipos guardados, existem as tabelas virtuais para o polimorfismo dinâmico, etc. Novamente tudo dependente de implementação.

O programador não tem que gerenciar essa memória, ela tem [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) por toda a aplicação.

Obviamente vários desses detalhes podem ser mais escrutinados em outras perguntas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Que resposta linda cara! Então por baixo é só uma função que recebe uma referência ao objeto como parâmetro, interessante!

Comment: Achei meia-boca, mas obrigado.

Comment: Bom, você respondeu todas as minhas dúvidas claramente, manteve a resposta no mesmo nível da pergunta (Não falou de coisas muito avançadas que não dê pra entender nem de coisas muito simples que fique chato) e eu quase chorei quando li a resposta. Então sim, ficou muito boa, talvez dê pra melhorar um pouco a escrita, mas isso não é o principal. Acredito que explicar mais básico do que isso não seria bom, já que uma pessoa que se interesse por esta pergunta muito provavelmente já vai saber e vai ficar exaustivo, e se ela não souber pode pesquisar suas dúvidas específicas em outras perguntas.