# O que é overhead?

Tags: terminologia, overhead

Vejo esse termo muito utilizado quando se trata da utilização excessiva da memória, mas não sei aprofundadamente se é realmente isso.

Percebi que aqui no site esse termo foi utilizado em algumas perguntas:

- [O tamanho de uma função afeta a performance e consumo de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31485/o-tamanho-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-afeta-a-performance-e-consumo-de-mem%C3%B3ria/31486#31486)
- [Qual o overhead de utilizar orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50273/qual-o-overhead-de-utilizar-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos/50308)
- [Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583)

A minha outra dúvida é que sempre vejo esse termo *overhead* sendo citado quando se fala em OOP (especificamente falando sobre discussões sobre o seu uso na linguagem PHP).

Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que significa, detalhadamente, o termo *overhead*?
- Existe alguma relação entre *overhead* e a programação orientada a 
  objetos?
- Como se pronuncia *overhead*? :)

Comment: Antes de alguém questionar sobre **"achar isso fácil no Google"**, leia a discussão no Meta: [É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham facilmente (como alguns julgam) no Google?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%C3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go)

Comment: Linha tênue....

Comment: Também acho que não é errado, mas se as fontes de pesquisas no Google são confiáveis, perdão, mas me parece como chover no molhado.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não vou discutir sobre isso. Várias perguntas que eu e outros fizeram aqui no site, que são "acháveis no Google", foram bem aceitas aqui.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo o Google só aponta para os sites que possuem as repostas, então por que não apontar para o SOpt? Achar as coisas no Google pode até ser fácil, mas achar conteúdo de qualidade é outra história! ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Overhead* é *overhead* não importa muito o contexto da computação.

Poderíamos traduzir como sobrecarga. A tradução literal seria "acima da cabeça". Indicaria que está acima do tamanho normal da pessoa.

Só se atente que no nosso contexto o termo é simplificado e na verdade ele é o *overhead cost*. Então a tradução é "pagar um preço extra por alguma coisa".

É muito comum que a criação de uma abstração cause algum *overhead*, mas o *holy grail* da computação é conseguir abstrações sem *overhead*. O oposto é obter um *overhead* sem um ganho em algum outro aspecto.

Esse custo adicional pode ser de processamento, consumo de memória, tempo em geral, transmissão, armazenamento, tamanho de código fonte, código final, uso, aprendizado, arquitetura, não importa, é *overhead* se precisa de algo a mais para conseguir o que se deseja, em geral em comparação com alguma outra coisa que em tese não tem *overhead*, pelo menos comparativamente.

Não entenda ele como algo inerentemente ruim. Ele pode ter um ganho compensador. Nem todo *overhead* pode ser eliminado, mesmo que se abra mão de alguma coisa pouco importante.

Em exemplo de *overhead* é o que não é o [*payload*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188469/101), é o que você paga de custo extra pra conseguir transmitir o dado.

Um TCP tem um *overhead* em relação ao UDP, mas ele tem algumas vantagens por isso tem custo maior.

Um código muito complicado tem um *overhead* para entender. Há o [*overhead* que um objeto precisa para o *booking* de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101).

Uma [função precisa se preparar e finalizar a execução do código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101) que ela tem que executar.

Uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) é um *overhead*.

Também pode ser exemplificado com o uso de uma VM.

Enfim, dá para citar milhares de exemplos.

OOP pode ter vários *overheads* e além dos mais técnicos, já demonstrados em pergunta *linkada*, existe o da aprendizagem já que não é simples aprender fazer direito e não abusar e o código se torna maior.

A pronúncia é "ôverréd". [Escute](https://howjsay.com/how-to-pronounce-overhead).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É como um **boné**, ele ajuda a proteger a cabeça dos raios solares, mas não é de graça. Mesmo se alguém te deu de presente, ele teve um custo para essa pessoa. De um jeito ou de outro, ele tem um custo, isso é chamado de _overhead_. O boné literalmente está "over head". ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Custo Adicional

Essa é a tradução que eu prefiro utilizar.

Embora possa ser utilizado em diversos contextos, eu entendo que o termo "custo adicional" parece dar um bom entendimento na maioria dos casos porque o termo sempre é usado com uma intenção de dizer que algo está a mais e esse algo a mais traz um custo de máquina, um custo de tempo, um custo de recurso, etc..

Uma analogia que acho interessante, e analogias precisam ser usadas com moderação, seria comparar o *overhead* a uma cobertura de bolo. Em algumas situações uma cobertura é essencial para caracterizar o bolo e em outros casos ela apenas deixa o bolo mais pesado, porém com o mesmo gosto.

O que eu quero dizer com isso é que ele é um termo que pode não remeter a algo ruim. Para cada caso é preciso entender se o *overhead* é algo ligado a um *trade off*, ou seja, algo adicional que tem um benefício, é apenas algo adicional que pode ser controlado ou é apenas uma característica da tecnologia. Para responder a sua questão de um *overhead* de forma detalhada é preciso adicionar um contexto porque para cada um você pode ter uma explicação detalhada diferente.

No caso da **OO**, eu entendo que o *overhead* é um *trade off*. Eu uso esse argumento porque é provável que nesse caso está sendo feito uma comparação a outro paradigma, por exemplo, o da programação estruturada. Ao fazer essa comparação vamos verificar vários pontos na **OO** que parecem "dar voltas" para atingir um mesmo objetivo e chama-se isso de *overhead*. É como se você adicionasse um custo de programação, de tempo, de compilação e de execução a um programa, que poderia ser escrito de uma forma mais simples e direta sem a necessidade do "custo adicional" colocado pela **OO**. Existem outros aspectos de um paradigma de programação que podem adicionar custos, por exemplo, custos de projeto, de documentação técnica, de ferramentas, de testes, etc. Embora em comparação à outro paradigma pareça trazer um custo a mais, entendo que é apenas a característica daquele paradigma, ou seja, ao adicionar esses custos tinha-se o objetivo de trazer algumas facilidades que o outro paradigma não tinha e por isso, que nesse caso, eu entendo ser um *trade off* e não um *overhead*.

Um exemplo de *overhead* mais claro está no seu exemplo do `SELECT *`. Nesse caso você está adicionando ao otimizador de consultas um custo adicional que é descobrir os nomes das colunas da tabela e alocar espaço para trazer todos os valores desses campos. Se você especificasse os nomes das colunas, evitaria esse custo adicional.

No caso da questão do desempenho de uma função estar relacionado ao tamanho dela, como pode ver naquela questão, é bastante relativo. Nesse caso eu não usaria o termo *overhead* porque o contexto é dinâmico e depende de existir uma implementação alternativa da função para servir de comparativo.