# Performance e segurança PHP x C++ para web

Tags: php, c++, aplicação-web, desempenho, segurança

Hoje trabalho numa empresa que gerencia alguns sites com um trafego demasiado grande, o que anda gerando alguns problemas de sobrecarga de servidor e etc. Esses sites em sua maioria são portais de notícias e estão rodando Wordpress, esses sites quanto mais crescem em volume de dados mais dragam recursos de forma exponencial.

Em minhas pesquisas surgir uma ideia se seria possível criar um CMS para grandes portais em C++ usando CGI, visando segurar estúpidas cargas de acessos e visando também a segurança e robustez.

Eis que me surge algumas dúvidas:

1 - C++ rodando sobre CGI realmente vai ser mais performático que PHP sobre Apache2? (Eu sei que isso depende muito da aplicação, mas levem em consideração uma aplicação bem escrita e arquitetada)

2 - Qual mais seguro deverá ser?

3 - Realmente poderá valer a pena criar um sistema desse tipo visando grandes portais?

Comment: Se estivesse preocupado com segurança sair do Wordpress seria a primeira coisa, eles mesmos [_admitem que segurança não é prioridade_](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39309#comment:17) e [problemas de segurança demoram mais de um ano para serem corrigidos](https://cedricvb.be/post/wordpress-stored-xss-vulnerability-4-1-2/) e o [mais recente (ainda não corrigido)](https://exploitbox.io/vuln/WordPress-Exploit-4-7-Unauth-Password-Reset-0day-CVE-2017-8295.html). Acho até irônico segurança e Wordpress junto numa mesma frase.

Comment: Nosso maior problema é que são muitos sites, e qual outra opção para migrar mantendo a facilidade do lado do cliente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 - C++ rodando sobre CGI realmente vai ser mais performático que PHP sobre Apache2? (Eu sei que isso depende muito da aplicação, mas levem em consideração uma aplicação bem escrita e arquitetada)

Sim, principalmente se usar [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) e evitar CGI que é lento. Mas não espere milagres. E também não espere que só porque deseja escrever algo bom, isso acontecerá com certeza. C++ é mais difícil.

WordPress tem o seu próprio [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101). Se escrever algo bom em PHP já terá um ganho enorme, mas se não souber fazer poderá ser até pior que o WP. Se escrever em C# talvez tenha uma performance próxima ao do C++ sem os riscos e dificuldades dele, principalmente se usar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

> 2 - Qual mais seguro deverá ser?

Segurança depende do código. Se bem feito não importa a linguagem. Como isso não costuma acontecer, o risco maior é usando C++.

> 3 - Realmente poderá valer a pena criar um sistema desse tipo visando grandes portais?

Só você pode responder isso. Já deixei claro que pra mim C# é a solução, é bem mais rápido que PHP e bem menos arriscado que C++, além de muito mais produtivo. Ajuda o fato que eu conheço isso, afinal a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você conhece. Tem quem prefira Java.

## Conclusão

Sinceramente, quando a pessoa pergunta isso ela não deveria se aproximar de C++ que exige um domínio da computação muito forte.