# Tem como ser notificado que haverá um coleta de lixo?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, garbage-collector

Estou estudando sobre o *garbage collector* do .NET e queria saber se existe algum evento que eu possa assinar e ficar sabendo sempre que uma coleta será feita.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evento mesmo não tem, isso seria pouco útil já que no momento que precisa fazer a coleta nada mais pode ser feito.

O que dá para fazer é ser notificado antes de uma alocação ser feita, não é algo simples e precisa montar um sistema de eventos próprio, de preferência em outra *thread*. Isso pode ser visto em [`GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_GC_RegisterForFullGCNotification_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Desta forma é possível saber quando uma alocação grande será feita e possivelmente gerar uma coleta e aí decidir o que fazer. Isso é útil para testes, mas pouco interessante em produção até porque tem [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101). Tem aplicação que notifica um *load balance* para não enviar mais requisições para ela até a coleta terminar, assim outra instância ou outro servidor pode continuar atende a demanda sem pausas. Não vejo uso em algo muito diferente disso.

Na documentação da classe `GC` tem várias coisas bem avançadas sobre o uso do GC. A configurabilidade e monitoramento do GC do .NET não é dos melhores, mas tem algumas coisas boas e está melhorando. Fora isto é possível usar ferramentas que ajudam diagnosticar questões de memória.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).