# O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

O que é **Garbage Collector**, como ele funciona?

Quando devemos nos preocupar com ele?

Comment: Relacionada: [Em quais momentos se faz necessário forçar a coleta de lixo em C# para um melhor desempenho da aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110854/em-quais-momentos-se-faz-necess%C3%A1rio-for%C3%A7a-a-coleta-de-lixo-em-c-para-um-melhor/110865#110865)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vou responder de forma geral e usar o GC do CLR como base. A segunda pergunta já foi [respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101).

## Gerenciamento de memória

Gerenciamento de memória é algo muito difícil.

Há uma definição (que não consegui achar a fonte original) que só 3 coisas revolucionaram o desenvolvimento de software:

- a linguagem de alto nível
- a modularização
- o gerenciamento automático de memória.

Enquanto alocamos na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) tudo é fácil e o gerenciamento pode ser feito de forma automática pela linguagem. Mas existem [inúmeras situações que o tempo de vida do objeto exige que ele fique no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101). Aí a aplicação é responsável por [liberar a alocação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

É comum o programador esquecer ou errar em quando liberar essa memória, inclusive porque há situações que é até difícil controlar em código o momento que a liberação é possível. Por isso pode haver vazamento de memória ou liberar algo que ainda está em uso.

Existem diversas técnicas que podem automatizar a liberação de memória. Estritamente todas elas podem ser chamadas de coleta de lixo já que ela libera a memória de algo que não precisa mais ser usada, portanto é aquilo virou lixo.

Algumas pessoas consideram que nem tudo que é liberado automaticamente é uma coleta. Alguns consideram apenas a coleta que é feita posteriormente ao objeto não ser mais necessário. É desta coleta que vamos falar. Não vou falar das coletas feitas por ponteiros inteligentes que gerenciam totalmente ou parcialmente o tempo de vida de forma única ou por contagem de referência. Eles são úteis, servem para muita coisa, possuem vantagens, mas não vem ao caso discutir aqui. Existem situações que eles não são adequados.

[Animações de como a memória se comporta com e sem coleta](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/09/03/visualizing-garbage-collection-algorithms/).

[image: Ilustração de coleta de lixo normal]

## Garbage Collector

O *garbage colletor* que tudo mundo fala é um mecanismo complexo de gerenciamento de memória que é responsável pela alocação e liberação da memória. É ele que decide onde colocar os objetos no *heap* e ele decide também quando liberar a memória e de que forma. Em geral chamamos ele de *tracing garbage collector*.

O mecanismo usado é de verificação do estado da memória para identificar o que está em uso e o que não está mais. Desta forma, não corre-se o risco de algo ficar para trás.

Isto é uma enorme simplificação para o programador porque ele pode fazer a bagunça que quiser e não precisa se preocupar com a memória (ou quase).

Isto é o que chamamos de memória gerenciada, base da filosofia do .NET. Você não pode corromper a memória e não tem vazamentos (se tomar certos cuidados).

Claro que isto tem um custo, tem desvantagens.

Este modelo tem um certo desperdício de memória. Ele só libera a memória de tempos em tempos, geralmente ele não retorna toda ou alguma memória para o sistema operacional.

Ele roda de forma não-determinística, você não sabe quando ele vai rodar, nem quanto tempo ele demorará para completar a coleta. Tem maneiras de ter algum controle em alguns mecanismos, mas geralmente é mal usado e não tem todo controle.

Por causa disto, liberação de recursos externos à aplicação podem ocorrer tardiamente se não tiver outro mecanismo para controlar isto.

Quase sempre ele gera pausas, algumas podem ser longas. Claro que depende da qualidade do mecanismo.

Tem outros detalhes mais específicos que o tornam indesejável em algumas situações, principalmente onde se exige tempo real, seja *soft real time*, ou mais ainda em *hard real time* que é complicado até mesmo com gerenciamento manual. Mesmo em algo bobo como um jogo, imagina você dar um tiro e ele só terminar alguns milissegundos depois. Ninguém vai morrer de fato, mas dá uma desvantagem para o jogador, que não é desejável.

Mas em ambiente de várias *threads*, onde tem exceções, objetos que circulam pela aplicação sem tempo de vida claramente definido, onde há abstrações que escondem certos efeitos de alocação, onde existem estruturas de dados com referência circular, é muito difícil funcionar sem esse gerenciamento automático.

A forma como ele aloca permite colocar os objetos próximos sempre, reduzindo a fragmentação de memória que é um enorme problema quando se faz gerenciamento manual ou automatizado de forma direta. Com os objetos próximos garante-se a localidade de referência e o cache é usado de forma mais eficiente dando mais performance na maioria dos casos. Tentar fazer algo semelhante na mão dá mais trabalho que escrever um GC. Então é possível ter esses ganhos sem um GC, mas quase sempre é inviável.

Com ele você trabalha com a memória como se ela fosse infinita, o problema de controlar o consumo não é do programador, é do GC, e se ele for bom ele fará melhor que o programador faria, exceto onde precisa do controle absoluto do consumo.

## Funcionamento

A coleta se dá olhando o que chamamos de raízes (*roots*), então ele começa olhando nos registradores do processador, na área estática do código e na pilha da aplicação (podem ser pilhas se tiver outras *threads*). A partir daí ele vai construindo um grafo de objetos referenciados. Em cada objeto que ele encontra pode ter outras referências para outros objetos, e assim ele vai recursivamente entrando no *heap*. Isto é chamado de fase de *mark*.

Depois vem a fase de liberação de memória. Tem diversas técnicas de fazer isto, entre elas o algoritmo de *sweep*, que vai liberando de verdade todos os objetos que não foram marcados com ativos.

[image: Grafo de objetos alcançáveis]

Tem também o algoritmo de *copy* que copia para outra área o que ainda está ativo e mata tudo o que existia. E tem ainda o algoritmo de *compact*, onde ele faz a cópia de forma especializada. É este que o .NET usa em parte. Mais ainda, ele usa um compactador geracional (por isso também usa o *sweep*).

Com as gerações de memória as pausas podem ser reduzidas, a alocação pode se tornar muito eficiente, bem mais que se fosse feita com gerenciamento manual ou automatizado de memória de outra forma, e permite ter estratégias diferentes de coleta para cada geração, produzindo o melhor resultado. Então é um mito que o GC sempre piora a eficiência de uso da memória.

Um coletor de lixo perfeito poderia ser mais eficiente que o gerenciamento manual ou automatizado de forma simples em quase todos os casos. Claro que dá para adotar estratégias manuais para ser muito eficiente, mas na prática iria criar mecanismo até mais complexo que os chamados coletores traçadores (*tracing garbage colllector*).

O .NET resolve o problema do não-determinismo usando um padrão de disponibilidade ([*disposing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)). Isto permite que o recurso seja liberado antes do GC rodar sempre que o objeto não é mais necessário. Claro que se isto não ocorrer, a liberação será feita pelo GC, o que fará a pausa ser maior e deixará o recurso vazado por mais tempo do que deveria. Um arquivo pode ficar aberto, por exemplo.

O .NET resolve o problema do [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) da cópia tendo uma área separada para grandes objetos, assim só os menores são copiados.

Mas as gerações causam um outro problema. Se o GC for chamado demais, ele tende a jogar para as gerações seguintes os objetos que tem tempo de vida curta, o que está longe do ideal já que cada geração tende a ter mais pausa e tende a ter mais *overhead*. Por isso você não deveria chamá-lo manualmente.

O GC geracional foi criado porque percebeu-se que os objetos costumam durar bem pouco tempo vivos ou então eles duram muito, possivelmente por toda execução da aplicação. Então o grosso das coletas ocorrerão cedo, quando é mais simples e rápido.

Obviamente que a forma específica de funcionamento do GC é detalhe de implementação. O GC dá algumas garantias, fora isto o programador não pode se valer desses detalhes de implementação.

Uma das coisas legais do GC é que a alocação de memória se dá com performance igual ou semelhante ao que precisa na *stack*. Na pilha a alocação apenas incrementa um ponteiro que costuma ficar no registrador, é muito rápido. Na geração 0 pode ser feito da mesma forma. Vai alocando em sequência só incrementando um ponteiro.

Em contraste com a alocação manual (a automatizada tradicional determinística não deixa de ser uma alocação manual, só está mais abstraída e tem um custo que não é trivial para alocar). Ele precisa achar onde alocar. Tem algoritmos eficientes pagando outro preço, ou de desperdício de memória, que pode ser pior que o GC, ou custo de liberação de memória muito alto. Tem otimizações que podem ser feitas, mas dá muito trabalho. Fica bem pior se a memória sempre tiver que pedir para o sistema operacional a memória que vai alocar. Também piora muito se tiver várias *threads* porque a alocação precisa ser travada, dá um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) do cão.

O GC do .NET tem uma área para cada processador existente, assim uma alocação nunca ocorre de forma concorrente e pode ser naturalmente atômica sem bloqueios (*locks*). É muito eficiente.

[image: Momentos de pausa entre as threads]

## Gen0

Geralmente, cada uma dessas áreas da Gen0 começa com 256KB (isso andou mudando, inclusive no .NET 7 passou ter regiões). Mas isto pode ser adaptado conforme a execução vai identificando que pode ser mais eficiente com outro tamanho, reduzindo o tempo de pausa ou diminuindo o número de pausas de acordo com o padrão de lixo gerado.

Quando esta área enche, dispara uma coleta. Então é feita a fase de marcação e copia tudo o que sobreviveu nesta área para a geração 1. O Java tem uma estratégia de copiar para uma área auxiliar ainda na Gen0 antes dando uma tempo a mais nesta geração. Isto é importante porque o Java produz muito mais lixo. Mas me parece que as implementações (Java tem vários GCs diferentes) não trabalham com 3 gerações.

Se tudo correr bem, pouca coisa é copiada, então o tempo de coleta é muito rápido, porque a coleta ocorre em uma operação muito simples librando todos os objetos que estava na Gen0, porque os que ainda deveriam permanecer vivos foram copiados. Fala-se em bem poucos microssegundos de pausa.

Quando há a cópia, todas as referências para ele precisam ser atualizadas para o novo endereço onde o objeto está agora, então não é só o custo de copiar o objeto.

Isto é um belo de um *overhead* e prejudica o cache já que tem que ficar acessando dados que efetivamente não estão sendo usados pela aplicação.

## Gen1

Na Gen1 não é necessário ter uma área para cada processador porque não é feita alocação concorrente (a alocação só ocorre quando o GC traz da Gen0), e pode ter um espaço maior. Geralmente nessa geração só caem objetos que viveram um tempo razoável na Gen0 e permaneceram vivos. Claro que alguns objetos que acabaram de ser criados acabam sendo copiados para ela, mas tirando essas exceções é comum que esses objetos copiados sobrevivam inclusive na Gen1 e passem para a Gen2, obviamente nem todos.

Fora isto a Gen1 funciona de forma muito semelhante, e o que sobrevive será copiado para a Gen2. Geralmente mais objetos sobrevivem e pode levar dezenas ou até centenas de vezes mais que a coleta da Gen0, o que pode significar, em grande parte dos cenários, alguma coisa como 1 milissegundo, o que pode não ser problema para maioria das aplicações, inclusive jogos, já que isso é uma porcentagem pequena do tempo gasto para renderizar um *frame*, considerando que a economia por não ter que ficar alocando e liberando memória pode ser maior que isto. Mas pode ser melhor ainda.

Como a Gen1 só recebe objetos em momentos específicos de coleta é mais fácil gerenciar a concorrência e assim é possível que a coleta dela ocorra de forma concorrente, ou seja, boa parte do processo de coleta pode ocorrer com a aplicação funcionando, então não gera uma pausa longa, ao contrário da Gen0 que precisa parar o funcionamento normal da aplicação para aplicar a coleta.

Mas tem um problema. Quando uma referência para um objeto é mudada pela aplicação possivelmente será para um objeto novo que está na Gen0 e isso é um problema. Porque a ideia da coleta geracional é que você não tenha que olhar toda memória.

Por isso o GC pode ser até mais eficiente que uma coleta manual, já que a alocação é muito simples, a liberação pode ser muito simples, e pode ter bem pouca cópia e varrer uma porção da memória muito pequena, e isto tudo pode ser mais eficiente que ficar alocando e liberando memória de forma individual em cada objeto.

Mas se um objeto da Gen1 ou 2 pode referenciar um objeto da Gen0, para saber se o objeto da Gen0 está livre de referências e pode ser descartado teria que olhar para a Gen1 e 2, ou seja, toda memória da aplicação, e perderia a eficiência.

Como não é tão comum assim mudar uma referência, o compilador faz um tratamento especial quando muda uma referência, avisando o GC disso, e ele cria uma tabela especial quando houver uma referência da Gen1 ou 2 para um objeto da Gen0. O custo de mudar uma referência é maior, em alguns raros cenários pode haver um desperdício de memória, mas assim você pode confiar em olhar só a geração que está coletando mais a tabela especial de objetos com referências anteriores, evitando ter que olhar a memória toda.

Eu não quero entrar em muitos detalhes sobre a concorrência da coleta, até porque varia de versão e até o modo de operação se está em uma aplicação típica servidora ou de cliente (interação com usuário). Fica o [*link* com a documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/background-gc) para quem quer se aprofundar ([também](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc)).

## Gen2

Na Gen2 o limite da memória praticamente não existe, especialmente em 64 bits (em 32 bite há o limite de 2GB por processo) e justamente por ser muita coisa e não ter que copiar para outra geração, o método de coleta muda completamente e é feito um *sweep* já citado anteriormente, ou seja, os objetos que não são mais usados são liberados em vez de serem copiados. E isto é útil porque se chegou na Gen2 poucos objetos são descartados, muitos deles são grandes (falarei mais depois).

A Gen2 consegue ser até mais concorrente com a aplicação que a Gen1, então as pausas que seriam grandes, podem não ser tão grandes assim, na maioria dos casos em não muitos milissegundos, raramente chegando em segundos.

Obviamente que a Gen2 provoca fragmentação de memória, mas por ter pouca liberação e os objetos serem maiores, não costuma ser um problema grande, pelo menos não maior que outras soluções manuais, e ainda pode ter as mesmas otimizações que o manual permite.

Em alguns casos a liberação da memória da Gen2 pode devolver a memória para o sistema operacional, nas gerações anteriores isto não ocorre, o que faz sentido, até porque é pouco memória para o padrão da maioria das aplicações.

## Large Object Heap

Acontece que essas cópias de objetos não custam caro quando os objetos são pequenos. Se os objetos são grandes ficar copiando pode custar tão caro que não compensa.

Considerando que a Gen2 não copia nada e apenas libera objetos, além de que objetos grandes não criam tanto problema de fragmentação (em alguns casos criam problemas maiores, mas é menos comum) a liberação é melhor para este tipo de objeto. Então colocar os objetos grandes na Gen2 é mais interessante, e é aí que inventaram o LOH (Large Object Heap) que fica junto da Gen2 e é liberada da mesma forma.

Objetos maiores de 85000 bytes indo direto para a Gen2 não sofrem do problema da cópia cara entre Gen0 e 1 e da Gen1 para a Gen2.

[Sobre as gerações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200713/101).

E [isso tem consequências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101).

## Liberação de recursos

O GC não para por aí. Além de liberar a memória ele precisa liberar recursos que não são gerenciados por ele.

Na verdade, o certo é o uso do [padrão de descarte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259882/101) ([*disposable pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101)). Se isso for feito certo o GC não precisa fazer nada, mas se houver falha do código em fazer a liberação dos recursos externos o GC precisa corrigir isso e fazer a liberação.

Isto é necessário porque o *tracing garbage collector* (e alguns outros tipos) não são determinísticos. Os de contagem de referência (entre alguns outros tipos) são determinísticos e não precisam disso, a liberação ocorre sempre no mesmo momento da liberação da memória, então o padrão pode ser opcional ou completamente desnecessário.

O custo de fazer essa operação prejudica o desempenho do GC e pode trazer algumas consequências indesejáveis se o padrão não for bem aplicado, mas não acho que mereça um detalhamento aqui.

[Ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101).

## GC moderno precisa de ajuda

Para o GC funcionar bem é necessário auxílio do compilador, é necessário ter estruturas com informações adicionais. Se não tivesse, só poderia usar o que se chama de GC conservador, onde só libera memória se tiver certeza que aquilo é uma referência para um objeto e nem sempre ele sabe, então esse é um mecanismo ruim onde muita memória vaza e otimizações não podem ser feitas. É neste tipo de GC que ele pegou a fama de ser ruim. Na prática ele não pode ser usado, necessitamos de um GC chamado de preciso.

## Outras linguagens

O .NET costuma ser melhor que o Java atual porque incentiva o uso da *stack* mais que o *heap*, e está fazendo isto cada vez mais.

Parece que há a intenção do JITter da JVM ou mesmo o compilador otimizar sozinho e colocar na *stack* algumas coisas quando identifica que o objeto é pequeno e tem tempo de vida garantido só na *stack*. O GC e o JITter do Java é mais esperto já que ele costuma abusar mais do *heap*. Costuma-se dizer que Java é uma linguagem que gera muito lixo. Tem até uma **piada**:

> Se Java realmente tivesse um coletor de lixo todo programa seria coletado no final da sua execução :)

Uma coisa que se fala do C++ é que ele não precisa de um coletor de lixo porque ele gera bem pouco lixo. Isto não é totalmente verdade, porque é menos sim, mas não é tão pouco assim. Dá trabalho não gerar tanto lixo em muitos casos, existe um GC no C++, ele só não é *tracejador*, e muitas vezes não é eficiente, e dá para viver sem. Algumas pessoas acabam usando um GC próprio com mecanismo de *tracing* em situações em que seja necessário.

## Conclusão

Note que tudo isto ocorre na implementação padrão, é possível mudar a forma do GC, ou até desativá-lo por completo com algum trabalho. Só não espere que as pessoas façam muito isto.

Não se engane, não estou dizendo que o GC é sempre melhor que outras formas, mas ele não é tão ruim quanto dizem. Tem casos que ele pode ser melhor, nos que ele é pior, a diferença não é tão absurda assim e quase sempre não faz diferença.

Não falei do [Pinned Object Heap](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/internals-of-the-poh/) porque ele é muito específico quando tem objetos que não podem mudar de lugar.

Para saber mais tem a [nossa querida *tag*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/garbage-collector?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Especialmente o [GC para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+garbage-collector).

Obviamente que cabem perguntas mais específicas sobre os vários tipos, técnicas, e especificidades sobre *garbage collecting*.

Muito do que ainda falta pode ser lido em outras respostas como por exemplo [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186644/101).

O Garbage Collector é uma das peças mais interessantes e impressionantes da engenharia de software, facilitando a vida do programador, criando confiabilidade e produtividade, e eventualmente até eficiência.

[Ver o GC do .NET funcionando](https://mattwarren.org/2016/06/20/Visualising-the-dotNET-Garbage-Collector/).

Para saber mais do que foi falado aqui sobre memória:

- [As variáveis são alocadas aleatoriamente na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252011/101)
- [Se um objeto manipulado por um ponteiro é alocado na heap, ele pode ser coletado pelo Garbage Collector?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/457340/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [O que torna um objeto elegível para ser alocado no stack?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121595/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)
- [Como uma classe é organizada na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [Garbage collector é automático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204344/101)
- [Tem como ser notificado que haverá um coleta de lixo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203095/101)
- [Impacto do Garbage Collector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153878/101)
- [Como funciona a relação do "using" e do garbage collector do .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422625/101)
- [Linguagem com Garbage Collector pode ser usada para jogos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205049/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

> Esta será daquelas respostas longas, estou quase acabando

Comment: Excelente explicação

Comment: "*Esta será daquelas respostas longas, mas vou fazer aos poucos. Os links virão depois. Calma que ainda vou organizar o texto.*" - Acho que já não precisa mais desse aviso, né?

Comment: @VictorStafusa esqueci disso, tá pela metade ainda, vou tentar finalizar hj ou no fds, obrigado :)

Answer (score -1):

> **Nota de autoria**
>   O conteúdo abaixo é majoritariamente composto por trechos de um [artigo](http://www.macoratti.net/14/09/c_garb1.htm) originalmente publicado pelo Macoratti em seu site. Reprodução [autorizada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkb4.png) pelo autor.

O coletor de lixo (*Garbage Collector*) do .NET *Framework* gerencia a alocação e liberação de memória para sua aplicação. Cada vez que você cria um novo objeto, o *Common Language Runtime* aloca memória para o objeto a partir do *heap* gerenciado. Enquanto os espaços de endereços estão disponíveis no *heap* gerenciado, o *runtime* continua a alocar espaço para novos objetos.

No entanto, a memória não é infinita. Eventualmente, o coletor de lixo deve executar uma coleta, a fim de liberar memória. O motor de otimização do coletor de lixo determina o melhor momento para realizar a coleta, com base nas alocações feitas.

Quando o coletor de lixo executa uma coleta, ele verifica se há objetos no *heap* gerenciado que não estão mais sendo usados pelo aplicativo e executa as operações necessárias para recuperar sua memória.

Assim, a  coleta de lixo é um processo que libera automaticamente a memória de objetos que não mais estão em uso. A decisão de recorrer ao processo de destruição é feita por um programa especial conhecido como coletor de lixo (*Garbage Collector*). No entanto, quando um objeto perde o escopo no final do método `Main()`, o processo de destruição não é necessariamente invocado.

Assim, você não pode determinar quando o método destruidor será chamado. O coletor de lixo também identifica os objetos que não são mais referenciados no programa e libera a memória alocada para eles. Você não pode destruir um objeto explicitamente no código. Na verdade, isso é uma prerrogativa do coletor de lixo, que destrói os objetos para os programadores. O processo de coleta de lixo acontece automaticamente. Ele garante que:

- Objetos são destruídos: Ele não especifica quando o objeto será destruído.
- Apenas os objetos não utilizados são destruídos: um objeto nunca é destruído se ele mantém a referência de um outro objeto.

C# fornece métodos especiais que são usados​para liberar a instância de uma classe a partir da memória, são eles : `Finalize()` e `Dispose()`.

**Finalize()**

O método destruidor `Finalize()` é um método especial que é chamado a partir de uma classe para qual ele pertence ou a partir de classes derivadas. Ele é chamado depois da última referência de um objeto ser liberada da memória.

**Dispose()**

O método `Dispose()` é chamado para liberar recursos, como a conexão com um banco de dados, tão logo o objeto usando o recurso não esta mais sendo usado. Diferente do método `Finalize()` o método `Dispose()` não é chamado automaticamente e você precisa chamá-lo explicitamente  a partir de uma aplicação cliente quando um objeto não mais for necessário.  A interface IDisposable contém o método `Dispose()` e por isso para chamar este método a classe precisa implementar esta interface.

**Comparação:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte](http://www.macoratti.net/14/09/c_garb1.htm)

Comment: E sim, a resposta tem erros, são detalhes, mas se for para responder com resposta do outros e tiver erro, pra que? Nada grave, é "enganoso". Eu sei que a culpa é da fonte original que foi um um pouco *sloppy*, mas você copiou e assume as consequências disto. Tem muita coisa na internet que explica algo sem que a pessoas entendam bem como funciona. Ou que ela até entende e não se preocupa em passar corretamente, ou ainda faz simplificações e não avisa sobre isto indicando que é apenas uma informação "a grosso modo" e não como realmente funciona. Induz as pessoas a erro.

Comment: @Maniero Não tenho problema algum com votos negativos, tenho problema em divulgar e difundir respostas erradas. Achava o motivo anterior cruel, porque se li e compreendo oque está sendo dito, não faz real diferença entre copiar o conteudo e reescreve-lo (Que acho mais desonesto). Agora tenho serio problemas em ler coisas erradas ou mesmo divulga-las

Comment: Em relação à questão da cópia, incluí um aviso no topo que deixa bem claro, desde o início, que o conteúdo é baseado em um original de outro site. Como se trata de uma reprodução (mesmo que editada), dar o link para o original apenas como "fonte", no fim, não é adequado. Uma fonte é qualquer conteúdo que influencie a elaboração de um texto de sua autoria. Mas se você transcreve trechos de uma fonte, deve deixar bem claro que se trata de uma transcrição. Em trechos curtos, com aspas e links. Em trechos longos, com um aviso ou algum tipo de formatação específica.

Comment: Sobre a qualidade técnica da resposta: eu não sou a melhor pessoa para avaliar, mas se a resposta tem erros o ideal é que eles sejam corrigidos ou pelo menos apontados aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @bfavaretto você ta certo, ficou muito melhor como formulou.