# Erro de logica em trabalho com lista

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como faço para o resultado ser igual à:

```
esta é a lista[{'h': 'h'}, {'h': 'j'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

```
a, b= ['h', 'j', 'z'], list()
c= dict()

for i in a:
    print(i)
    c['h']= i
    print(c)
    b.append(c)
    
print(f'esta é a lista{b}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Considere essa leitura introdutória:

> Python é uma linguagem altamente orientada a objetos . Na verdade, virtualmente todos os
> itens de dados em um programa Python são objetos de um tipo ou classe específica.
>
> Considere este código:
> `>>> print(300)`
> `300`
>
> Quando apresentado com a declaração print(300), o intérprete faz o seguinte:
>
> - Cria um objeto inteiro
> - Dá valor 300
> - Exibe no console
>
> Uma variável Python é um nome simbólico que é uma [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia) para um objeto.
> Depois que um objeto é atribuído a uma variável, você pode se referir ao objeto por esse
> nome. Mas os próprios dados ainda estão contidos no objeto.
>
> Por exemplo:
> `>>> n = 300`
>
> Esta atribuição cria um objeto inteiro com o valor `300` e atribui a variável `n` para
> apontar para esse objeto.
> [image: Atribuição de Variável]
>
> Agora considere a seguinte afirmação:
> `>>> m = n`
>
> O que acontece quando ele é executado?
> Python não cria outro objeto. Ele simplesmente
> cria um novo nome simbólico ou referência `m` que aponta para o mesmo objeto para o qual
> `n` aponta.
> [image: Múltiplas referências para um único objeto]
>
> Em seguida, suponha que você faça isso:
> `>>> m = 400`
>
> Agora o Python cria um novo objeto inteiro com o valor `400` e `m` se torna uma
> referência a ele.
> [image: Referências a objetos separados]
>
> Por último, suponha que esta instrução seja executada a seguir:
>
> `>>> n = "foo"`
>
> Agora o Python cria um objeto string com o valor `"foo"` e faz `n` referência a ele.
> [image: Objeto Órfão]
>
> Não há mais nenhuma referência ao objeto inteiro  `300`. Ele está órfão e
> não há como acessá-lo.
>
> A vida de um objeto começa quando ele é criado, momento em que
> pelo menos uma referência a ele é criada. Durante a vida útil de um
> objeto, referências adicionais a ele podem ser criadas, como visto
> acima, e referências a ele também podem ser excluídas. Um objeto
> permanece vivo, por assim dizer, enquanto houver pelo menos uma
> referência a ele.
>
> Quando o número de referências a um objeto cai para zero, ele não está
> mais acessível. Nesse ponto, sua vida útil acabou. O Python acabará
> percebendo que está inacessível e recuperará a memória alocada para
> que possa ser usada para outra coisa. No jargão da informática, esse
> processo é conhecido como [coleta de lixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255769/o-que-%C3%A9-garbage-collector-e-como-ele-funciona).
>
> <sup>Fonte: Traduzido e adaptado de [Real Python - Variáveis ​​em Python](https://realpython.com/python-variables/)</sup>

Ciente disso, de cara são identificados dois problemas com o seu código:

1. Na linha `c['h']= i`  a cada iteração sobre os elementos de `a` o valor cujo o objeto da chave `h`, contida no objeto referenciado por `c`, referencia é sobrescrito pela referência contida em `i`. Pois um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) Python não possui chaves duplicadas a cada novo valor escrito numa chave substitui o anterior.
2. Na linha `b.append(c)` a cada iteração sobre os elementos de `a` a mesma referencia ao objeto referenciado por `c` é repetidamente apensada a lista referenciada por `b`.

Veja:

```
a, b= ['h', 'j', 'z'], list()
c= dict()

for i in a:
    print(i)
    #A cada iteração é sobrescrito o valor da chave h ao objeto referenciado por c.
    c['h']= i   
    print(c)
    #A cada iteração a mesma referencia a c é adicionado a lista em b.
    b.append(c)  
    
print(f'esta é a lista{b}')
```

Resultando em:

```
h
{'h': 'h'}
j
{'h': 'j'}
z
{'h': 'z'}
esta é a lista[{'h': 'z'}, {'h': 'z'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

O reparo imediato para o seu código funcionar como quer é fazer com que a sobrescrição de dados indesejada em `c['h']= i` e a reiterada adição a mesma referência em `b.append(c)` deem lugar a criação literal de uma estrutura do tipo `{'h': i}` e o apensar dessa estrutura em `b`.

```
a, b= ['h', 'j', 'z'], list()
#c= dict()                     #Não é mais necessário. 

for i in a:
    print(i)
    c = {'h': i}               #A cada iteração cria um dicionário literal e o referencia em c.
    print(c)
    b.append(c)                #Apensa em b a referência em c.
    
print(f'esta é a lista{b}')
```

Resultando:

```
h
{'h': 'h'}
j
{'h': 'j'}
z
{'h': 'z'}
esta é a lista[{'h': 'h'}, {'h': 'j'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

Simplificado o código:

```
a, b= ['h', 'j', 'z'], list()
for i in a:
    b.append({'h': i})               
        
print(f'esta é a lista{b}')
#esta é a lista[{'h': 'h'}, {'h': 'j'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

Ainda usando [compreensões de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [{'h': i} for i in ['h', 'j', 'z']] 
print(f'esta é a lista{l}')
#esta é a lista[{'h': 'h'}, {'h': 'j'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

Comment: Ajuda bem didática, assumo que vim ver a resposta primeiro mas logo voltarei para ler o por que ocorreu o "erro". Hoje eu também estava com a logica bem fraca, sabia do erro mas nem raciocinava como concertar. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O que você tá fazendo no loop é adicionar uma referência pro dicionário C no final da lista. Toda vez que você alterar C, vai alterar, essas alterações serão refletidas na lista.

Pra fazer o que você tá querendo seria preciso criar um novo dicionário na hora de colocá-lo na lista:

```
for i in a:
    c['h']= i
    # A linha abaixo cria uma cópia do dicionário 
    # e coloca no final da lista
    b.append(dict(c))
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa usar **FOR** para isso, basta criar uma lista *inline* que vai gerar um dicionário.

```py
a = ['h', 'j', 'z']
c = [{a[0] : i} for i in a]

print(f'esta é a lista{c}')
```

Output:

```
esta é a lista[{'h': 'h'}, {'h': 'j'}, {'h': 'z'}]
```

Esse modo pode ser considerado um pouco mais *pythônico*.

Comment: Na realidade eu preciso do FOR é que essa parte do código é fragmento de outra que tem quase a mesma função, porem ela ao invés de lista percorre uma pagina WEB. Mas valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Nesse caso sugiro adicionar essa informação sobre a necessidade do uso do FOR na sua pergunta.

Comment: Sei que há a necessidade, mas hoje fiz essa pergunta só porque eu estou cansado demais. Em situações normais ja saberia resolver. E caso não utilizasse o FOR eu implementaria, esta tranquilo. Valeu novamente pela ajuda e pela observação;