# POO duvida objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com uma dúvida sobre POO...

```
Classe objeto=new Classe();
```

...pelo que eu entendi, criamos uma variável que recebe uma referencia do objeto criado.

Em uma lista encadeada simples quando eu excluo um nó, eu digo que o nó que apontava para o nó que eu exclui, vai passar a apontar para nada(null).

Minha duvida é apesar daquele nó que eu exclui não poder mais ser acessado, ele continua existindo?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas se sua dúvida é sobre trocar a referência de um objeto por outra numa variável, o objeto que perdeu a referência será apagado da memória pelo Garbage Collector.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255769/o-que-%c3%a9-garbage-collector-e-como-ele-funciona)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se cria uma instância de uma classe, então a variável é uma referência para o objeto em memória.

Se excluir (aqui vou assimir, setar `null* ) a uma referência, aquele objeto não pode mais ser acessado em memória, e o espaço que ele ocupa ficará disponível para ser sobrescrito, mas se apagar só a refência a ele em outro objeto, ele continua existindo.

Então, sobre a sua pergunta *"apesar daquele nó que eu exclui não poder mais ser acessado, ele continua existindo?"* **existindo** é um conceito relativo. Uma lista encadeada com referências de objetos, por exemplo:

```
Lista > obj1 > obj2 > obj3 ...
```

Se apagar na lista a referência do do obj3 em obj2 (por exemplo `obj3.setNo(null)`) , ele deixa de existir para a lista, mas o obj3 ainda existe em memória.

Veja esse exemplo simples de uma lista que demostra que, uma o objeto "deixa de existir" para o programa:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var lista = new Classe();
        var no1 = new Classe();
        var no2 = new Classe();
        
        no1.setNo(no2);
        lista.setNo(no1);
        
        System.out.println("Lista com todos os nos");
        System.out.println(lista.getNo()); // retorna a instancia de no1
        System.out.println(lista.getNo().getNo());// retorna a instancia no2
        
        no1.setNo(null); // seto null, removendo a referencia ao no2 que existia no no1
        System.out.println("Lista sem o no2");
        System.out.println(lista.getNo());  // retorna a instancia no1
        System.out.println(lista.getNo().getNo());  // retorna null, a referencia a no2 foi quebrada
        System.out.println(no2); // o objeto no2 ainda existe
    }
}

class Classe {
    private Classe no;
    
    public Classe getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    
    public void setNo(Classe no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
}
```

E o output é:

```
Lista com todos os nos
Classe@1175e2db
Classe@36aa7bc2
Lista sem o no2
Classe@1175e2db
null
Classe@36aa7bc2
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.mycompiler.io/](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/BmLnLgt)