# Por que métodos que operem ponteiros são inseguros no .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ponteiro

Lendo um pouco do código fonte do .NET percebi que alguns métodos possuem um modificador peculiar, o `unsafe`.

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FriendAccessAllowed]
internal unsafe static Boolean TryStringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, ref NumberBuffer number, StringBuilder sb, NumberFormatInfo numfmt, Boolean parseDecimal) {   

    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Contract.Assert(numfmt != null, "");

    fixed (char* stringPointer = str) {
        char * p = stringPointer;
        if (!ParseNumber(ref p, options, ref number, sb, numfmt, parseDecimal) 
            || (p - stringPointer < str.Length && !TrailingZeros(str, (int)(p - stringPointer)))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

A documentação é clara sobre o modificador:

> A palavra-chave unsafe denota um contexto inseguro, que é requerido para qualquer operação envolvendo ponteiros. [Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

- O que faz esse modificador?
- Por que contextos que envolvam manipulação de ponteiros são considerados inseguros no .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que faz esse modificador?

O modificador só indica para o compilador que você vai usar código inseguro e portanto ele deve permitir que esse código seja considerado válido.

Para compilar um código `unsafe` é preciso dizer isso ao compilador com a [*flag* `/unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Os desenvolvedores da linguagem queriam dar a facilidade de manipular dados de forma mais livre que o normal que o C# permite, mas não queriam que isso fosse feito sem ser explícito, não queriam que abusassem disso. O que até poderia facilitar algumas otimizações em outros pontos.

Note que o seu uso muda as características de segurança da aplicação e pode exigir o uso de forma um pouco diferente do normal. Pode até não conseguir executar em certos cenários. O código se torna inverificável pelo [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

> Por que contextos que envolvam manipulação de ponteiros são considerados inseguros no .NET?

O ponteiro bruto é o principal mecanismo inseguro da linguagem, mas ele é útil para interoperabilidade com outras linguagens, principalmente C e também para obter mais performance acessando a memória de forma direta, da mesma forma que o C faz.

Não que ele seja completamente livre e que a memória deixe de ser gerenciada quando o faz, mas pode acessar de forma equivocada partes de dados e provocar resultados inesperados que não são normais dentro do que é normalmente aceito no C#.

Dependendo de como for usado é possível abrir uma brecha de segurança e um dado externo interferir no acesso à memória e ter os problemas que normalmente uma linguagem como C ou C++ tem. Ainda que um pouco mais limitado já que não pode acessar posições arbitrárias de memória, tem que pegar endereço de um objeto existente.

## Ponteiros

O ponteiro não tem os mesmos controles de acesso que outras formas possuem, formas estas que tornam o código mais lento. Em geral o controle de acesso de *array* é o responsável por isso. Note que o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) pode eliminar isso e a velocidade ficar a mesma do uso de ponteiros. Ainda que o cenário mais comum onde é possível eliminar este [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) tenha outros custos.

Há alguma limitação de como pode usar o ponteiro, ele não pode apontar para qualquer tipo, só os tipos por valor são aceitos (o ponteiro é um tipo por valor). Existe uma restrição para tipos que possuam tipos por referência como um dos seus membros (você pode apontar para um `char` dentro de uma `string`, mas não pode apontar para uma `string`).

Inclui aí o `void *` que é um ponteiro para um tipo desconhecido, mas ele não pode acessar qualquer coisa, se quiser usá-lo para acessar outro tipo precisa de um *cast* para o tipo para deixar claro a intenção, o que na prática torna seu uso mais seguro e menos útil que em C (C3 tem mecanismos melhores).

Ponteiros saem do sistema de tipos normal do C#, portanto não herdam do `Object` e não podem ser usados normalmente.

A segurança de tipos é relaxada, mas não desligada.

Com o advento do [`Span<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0) o uso de ponteiro se torna menos necessário ainda. Ele faz uso de mecanismo inseguro internamente, assim você não precisa usar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

**O que faz esse modificador?**

Blocos de código formados com `unsafe` permitem o uso de ponteiros dentro dele, exemplo:

```
using System;
class MyClass {
    public unsafe static void Main() {
        int numero = 10;
        int* pNumero = &numero;
        Console.WriteLine("numero é " + numero);
        Console.WriteLine("endereço é " + (int)pNumero );
    }
}
```

se aí não tivesse `unsafe`, um erro de compilação aconteceria.

**Por que contextos que envolvam manipulação de ponteiros são considerados inseguros no .NET?**

Acredito que ponteiros são relativamente "inseguros" em qualquer ambiente, não só .NET, porque se usados de forma errada, podem resultar em comportamentos inesperados, ou *undefined behaviors*. Em C#, o que você normalmente esperaria que disparasse uma exceção, poderia simplesmente ter como output um valor estranho ou inesperado, devido ao uso de ponteiros.

Raramente é útil o uso de ponteiros em C#, mas há algumas situações em que pode ser útil, como algum trecho de código em que é necessário ter a performance o mais alta possível

Answer (score 4):

**C# é uma linguagem com segurança de tipo (type-safety)**

*Mas o que seria segurança de tipo?* O jeito mais fácil de explicar isto é explicando como seria o *contrário* disto.

Em linguagens como o `C` ou `C++` você pode fazer coisas *poderosas* no cenário *correto* (e *perigosas* se não tomar cuidado), como tratar um tipo de dado como um outro tipo totalmente diferente, sem converter ou *castar* este elemento para o tipo especificado.

Por exemplo, você pode pegar um ponteiro de um `char` e tratá-lo como se fosse um ponteiro do tipo `int`. Isto é comum e aceitável nestas linguagens. A linguagem **realmente** lê os `bytes` do valor do ponteiro especificado e interpreta eles do jeito *errado*.

Esta é a definição do contrário do que seria uma operação com "segurança de tipo" ou "type-safety".

No `C#`, temos o que chamamos de segurança de tipo (type-safety), em que o compilador assegura que *aquele* objeto *realmente* é daquele tipo, o que previne que este tipo de coisa seja feita, não permitindo o acesso a ponteiros, todavia, ao adicionar o modificador `unsafe`, você sai desta zona de *conforto e segurança* e pode abusar de ponteiros e tipos como o próprio `C/C++` (ainda assim com um pouco de segurança).

Obviamente, no C# você pode tentar *castar* um objeto de um tipo para outro tipo, mas se o compilador detectar que realmente é *impossível* a conversão entre estes dois tipos, ele vai acusar erro de compilação. Mesmo que que o compilador aceite o `cast` de tipos não compatíveis, o `runtime` vai lançar erro na execução.

Há também a linguagem dinâmica no `C#`, que funciona mais ou menos como o `unsafe`, porém sem o acesso a ponteiros.