# O que são ponteiros?

Tags: c#, c, .net, windows, ponteiro

Já me deparei com isso em várias linguagens, principalmente C e C++, mas nunca entendi o que é, como se usa, e porque existe. Descobri sem querer que também existe em C# e é uma prática *não segura*.

Para que servem os ponteiros? Como usá-los? Quando são úteis?

Também li que ponteiros são *referências* para as variáveis, que isso é possível fazer com `out` e `ref` em C# (isso não existe em C++ até onde sei). Qual seria a diferença disso com esses tais ponteiros?

```
public unsafe void Foo(char* teste) {
    *teste = 'A';
}
public void Bar(ref char teste) {
    teste = 'A';
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Boa parte das perguntas específicas aqui [já foram respondidas em outras perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244828/101).

Ponteiros são [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Eles podem ser chamados de apontadores. Como eles apontam para algo, eles são sempre um endereço de alguma coisa, de algum lugar. Embora possa ser usado em outros contextos, em programação de forma geral, esses endereços são de memória e apontam para objetos que estão nessa posição. Então podemos dizer que o ponteiro é a posição (coordenada) onde fica a sua casa. latitude e longitude, rua e número na cidade tal.

Um ponteiro costuma ter 4 ou 8 bytes e em dispositivos antigos, ou atuais bem limitados, podem ter 2 ou até 1 byte, salvo as arquiteturas exotéricas. Duvido que um dia precisará mais que 8 bytes que já permite endereçar mais que toda informação produzida no mundo atualmente em um único dispositivo, ou seja, pode endereçar 2 elevado a 64 posições. Nenhuma arquitetura atual sequer suporta nem perto disso.

[Então ele é um número inteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91365/101), de forma geral positivo, que indica a posição de memória de um objeto qualquer.

Ele pode ser armazenado em um registrador do processador, em algum nível de cache, RAM ou até em outro local, embora se ele for usado em um processo diferente ou persistido, é quase certo que algo não funcionará em outro momento de execução.

Assim como qualquer número armazenado, pode-se atribuir um nome no código para ele, ou seja, ele pode ficar em uma variável. Tecnicamente um ponteiro aponta para uma posição da memória, no nível mais alto essa posição pode até estar sendo indicada no código com um nome de [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

A indireção é importante para dar flexibilidade e [permitir uma série de truques que facilitam a criação de estruturas e algoritmos adequados para um requisito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101). Se não tivesse o ponteiro tudo o que você precisa teria que ser usado de forma linear, teria que [copiar os dados que precisa duplicando-os](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205587/101), complicaria o gerenciamento da memória, o acesso seria extremamente lento (quase tudo que tem complexidade O(1) hoje teria que ser O(n), é uma diferença brutal), entre outros problemas.

Um [*array* é viável por causa do ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). A [alocação dinâmica só funciona por causa dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101).

Pensa no índice de um livro, ele tem ponteiros para as páginas onde aquela informação está no livro. Ou em um trabalho que você faz e diz em que página do livro foi obtido aquilo. Imagina sem essa informação como complica achar o que quer, teria que procurar no livro todo.

Ponteiro é um conceito abstrato que tem algum suporte do processador para lidar com ele. As linguagens de programação possuem formas de implementar o acesso aos ponteiros de forma um pouco mais fácil para um humano. [Linguagens como C melhoram um pouco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106231/101), mas não muito porque você ainda tem que mexer com o ponteiro.

Outras linguagens preferem, ou só permitem, usar uma [referência, que no fundo é um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) mais controlado.

[O ponteiro do C# é um meio termo entre ponteiro e referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244754/101). É inseguro, mas não tanto quanto em C porque ele não permite acessar endereço arbitrário da memória sem controle. [`out`, `ref` e o novo `in`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101) são referências, ou seja, são ponteiros para algum objeto na memória, mas não é possível manipular o ponteiro da forma que quiser, o compilador faz todo o trabalho e controle para você. Os objetos criados com classes e delegados usam referências, mas internamente são ponteiros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Apenas complementando, em C++ você pode usar referências quando você define na assinatura de uma função que o argumento será passado com & por exemplo void func(int &var). Neste caso a variável será passada por referência e será modificada dentro da função, mas sem toda a liberdade dos ponteiros "crus" (raw pointer)

Comment: Para complementar: Ponteiros são dependentes de plataforma, em c# existe um objeto que representa o ponteiro da plataforma específica: IntPtr. Além disso o fato de ser inseguro se refere ao constante fato de ser fácil de errar com ponteiros e causar o famoso "segmentation fault", com vetor fortemente tipado se você extrapola seus limites o framework faz a checagem e gera uma exceção e você pode tratá-la normalmente, com ponteiros não há nenhum tipo de conferência... Apesar dessa carterística ponteiros são bastante úteis se precisar de otimização extrema, ganha-se algumas instruções de máquina.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar, em C++ as referências são definidas usando o operador &.

Assim podemos ter:

```
int number = 5;
int &myRef = number;
```

E podemos ter:

```
void func(int &var){...}
```

Esse segundo caso talvez seja mais interessante porque ele define que a variável passada para a função vai como referência, isso significa que ela poderá ter seus valores modificados, porém sem toda a liberdade dos ponteiros "crus" (raw pointer). Em especial, uma referência não pode ser redefinida, ou seja, passar a apontar para outro endereço.