# Dúvida em c (listas encadeadas e vetor)

Tags: c

Como posso fazer para criar um vetor em que cada posição é um ponteiro para uma lista encadeada ?

Por exemplo:

```
typedef struct info Info
struct info {
 int num;
 Info* prox;
};
```

E depois quero criar um vetor, e fazer algo do tipo, mas com alocação dinâmica do tamanho:

Por exemplo:

```
v[0] = colocarnum(lista, 10);
```

Comment: Uma lista ligada é diferente de um vector qual o objectivo do vector final?

Comment: A ideia é que cada índice da lista tenha um ponteiro que leva a uma lista ligada contendo informações.

Comment: `Info* vetor[10];` ou `vetor = (Info *) malloc(10 * sizeof(Info *));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o IME-SP, um lista encadeada significa:

> Listas encadeadas. Uma lista encadeada é uma representação de uma sequência de objetos, todos do mesmo tipo, na memória RAM (= random access memory) do computador. Cada elemento da sequência é armazenado em uma célula da lista: o primeiro elemento na primeira célula, o segundo na segunda, e assim por diante. ([https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html))

em C, podemos criar uma lista simplesmente encadeada definindo uma estrutura LISTA que irá conter os dados da lista e um ponteiro do tipo struct para o proximo elemento da lista.

> (Duvidas sobre ponteiros, acesse o link:
>
> [O que são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266756/o-que-s%C3%A3o-ponteiros?rq=1)

No seu caso, como trata-se de uma lista simplesmente encadeada, a lista irá apontar apenas para frente, ou seja para o proximo elemento. Mas poderiamos fazer uma lista que possuisse ponteiros que apontassem tanto para o proximo quanto para o anterior. Vamos dar uma olha no codigo de implementacao abaixo para entender melhor:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
/* Definicao da estrutura lista que tera o apelido do "no" */
typedef struct lista {
    int vetorDeNumeros[10];
    struct lista *prox;
} no;

void inserir(int x, no *p) {
    /* Inserir um elemento a lista */
}

void excluir(no *p) {
    /* Excluir um elemento a lista */
}

void busca (int x, no *le) {
    /* Buscar um elemento a lista */
}

void imprimir(no *le) {
    /* imprimir um elemento a lista */
}

int main (void) {
    /* Criando um vetor dinamico  da lista */
    int tamLista;
    int tamVetores;
    no* vetorDinamico;
    printf("Quantas listas seu vetor irá possuir? R: ");
    scanf("%d",&tamLista);
    getchar();
    /* Alocando dinamicamente o tamanho do vetor lista*/
        vetorDinamico = (no *) malloc(tamLista * sizeof(no));
    /* Alocando dinamicamente o tamanho dos vetores de numeros dentro de lista do vetor dinamico*/
            for (int i = 0; i<tamLista; i++) {
                printf("Quantas posicoes terá o vetor da sua lista numero %d? R: ",i);
                scanf("%d",&tamVetores);
                vetorDinamico[i].vetorDeNumeros[tamVetores] = (long) malloc(tamVetores * sizeof(long));
            }
/* adicionando numeros dentro de uma lista dentro de um vetorDinamico */
vetorDinamico[0].vetorDeNumeros[0] = 1;
/* Teste de impressao de um vetor de inteiro dentro de um vetor dinamico de lista chamado no */
printf("O Numero armazenado na posicao 0 do vetor 0 da estrutura é: %d",vetorDinamico[0].vetorDeNumeros[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

O Codigo nada mais faz que:

1. criar uma estrutura LISTA com o nome de NO com um vetor de numeros dentro dela;
2. criar um vetor dinamico da estrutura lista e alocar a memoria do vetor dinamicamente;
3. criar um vetor de numeros dentro de cada lista atribuida ao vetor dinamico de lista e alocar a memoria destes vetores dinamicamente
4. imprimir um numero teste.

Espero que tenha esclarecido sua duvida.

Answer (score 0):

Com uma lista ligada os valores são percorridos através dos campos `prox`.

```c
typedef struct info {
    int num;
    struct info *prox;
} Info;

int main(void) {
    Info *info1, *info2;
    info1 = (Info *) malloc(sizeof(Info));
    info2 = (Info *) malloc(sizeof(Info));
    
    info1->num = 1;
    info2->num = 2;
    info1->prox = info2;
    
    printf("Valor 1 -> %d\n", info1->num);
    printf("Valor 2 -> %d\n", info1->prox->num);
    
    free(info2);
    free(info1);


    return 0;
}
```

Caso tenha um vector de ponteiros para `Info` irá ter uma lista de listas.