# Por que um vetor em C é passado como parâmetro por referência?

Tags: c, array, parâmetros, referência

Por que todos os outros tipos de variáveis passadas como parâmetro para uma função são passadas por valor e o vetor não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os tipos de dados são passadas como argumentos por valor para o [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

O vetor é dado que guarda um ponteiro, este é o valor dele. O ponteiro aponta para um outro objeto em outra posição de memória, então você passa o valor que é um ponteiro, e a característica do ponteiro é ater um outro objeto apontado. A passagem de argumento não muda nada, a forma de acessar o objeto é que muda, são mecanismos diferentes. O acesso ao objeto será por referência, mas ele é assim mesmo sem a passagem de argumento.

Conceituando certo cada coisa, fica mais fácil entender.

Veja mais em:

- [O que são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266756/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)