# Metodo recursivo ou loop para popular ou listar um array n-dimensional

Tags: java, loop, recursão, array-multidimensional

Estou tentando construir um método capaz de preencher uma matriz n-dimensional em todas as posições, por exemplo: eu tenho uma matriz com 2 dimensões, onde essa matriz é 2x2 com apenas 2 dimensões em um plano cartesiano, por exemplo.

Eu gostaria que o mesmo método preenchesse uma matriz com 3 dimensões ainda 2x2, no entanto, eu não gostaria de colocar fixo no código no caso do *loop* de duas dimensões um dentro do outro e quando é tridimensional 3 também um *loop* dentro do outro. Preciso usar o mesmo código multidimensional, por exemplo: 8 dimensões com uma matriz 2x2.

Meu exemplo 2D:

```
int matrix2d [] [] = new int [2] [2];
for (int i = 0; i <matrix2d.length; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <matrix2d [i] .length; j ++) {
        System.out.println ("(" + i + "," + j + ")");
    }
}
```

Resultado:
(0.0) (0.1) (1.0) (1,1)

Meu exemplo 3D:

```
int matrix3d [] [] [] = new int [2] [2] [2];
for (int i = 0; i <matrix3d.length; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <matrix3d [i] .length; j ++) {
        for (int l = 0; l <matrix3d [i] [j] .length; l ++) {
            System.out.println ("(" + i + "," + j + "," + l + "));
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:
(0.0.0) (0.0.1) (0.1.0) (0.1,1) (1.0.0) (1.0,1) (1,1,0) (1,1,1)

Gostaria de ter um método ou *loop* genérico, não precisando incluir um *loop* a cada vez que aumentar a dimensão.

Comment: Já tentou linearizar sua matriz?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773536/5524514

Comment: Já fiz isso, mais precisaria conforme os indices postados dos resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu não sei o propósito do código, aí vai uma maneira bem básica de criar os pontos da matriz, usando recursão:

```
private static int numLinha;

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    int dims = 5;
        int size = 3;
    numLinha = 0;
    getMatrix(dims, size);
}

private static void getMatrix(int dims, int size) {
    int[] arr = new int[dims];
    getMatrixPoint(0, 0, dims, arr, size);
}

private static void getMatrixPoint(int pos, int index, int currDim, int[] arr, int size) {

    //condicao de fim de recursao
    if (currDim == 0) {
        String strPoint = "(";
        String sep = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            strPoint = strPoint + sep + arr[i];
            sep = ", ";
        }
        strPoint = strPoint + ")";
        System.out.println(++numLinha + " - " + strPoint);
        return;
    }

    //para cada possivel valor da primeira dimensao
    //calcule os possiveis pontos da (quantidade_de_dimensoes - 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[pos] = i;
        getMatrixPoint(pos + 1, i, currDim - 1, arr, size);
        arr[pos] = 0;
    }
}
```

Para uma matriz de tamanho size e número de dimensões dims, serão gerados size^dims pontos.
Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OOCpDP)

Comment: Tentarei aplicar isso no meu problema, na verdade eu tenho um algoritmo de agrupamento que fará o seguinte, precisarei montar uma matriz e verificar se dentro dela, há pontos, porém, posso ter a matriz em n dimensões, então sem saber qual seria a entrada do problema, preciso fazer que a matriz seja montada em n dimensão. Obrigado pela contribuição, vou tentar aplicar no meu problema e retorno aqui para comentar.

Comment: Deu certo, utilizei esse retorno para criar meu algoritmo, muito obrigado, só estou com outro problema agora e vou tentar mudar no código que me passou, neste caso a matriz está quadrada ex: 5x5, preciso conseguir quando me passarem um valor não quadrado ex: a entrada de 25 células, seria feito o algoritmo com 5x5 = 25 células; porém, o algoritmo pode receber tamanhos não quadrados, ex: 8 células e neste caso deveria montar uma matriz 4x2, 2x4, ou até mesmo uma entrada 5 células que deveria montar uma matriz 5x1.

Comment: Nesse caso, do "top of my head", você poderia passar arrays de informações, i.e., arrays de pos, index, currDim e size (arr[] continua sendo um array das coordenadas do ponto, aliás point seria um nome melhor para a variável).

Answer (score 5):

É muito difícil existir problemas reais com mais que 3 ou 4 dimensões. Se tiver um problema assim ou ele está definido errado ou é melhor achar um solução diferente.

Mesmo que tenha um problema assim ele cresce exponencialmente e vai precisa de muita eficiência. Esta generalização criará um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) na execução para controlar o laço que conta as dimensões, o que é um peso maior em algo que se tornará muito pesado.

Até tem como fazer, mas a engenharia correta disto é não fazer. Melhor criar o caso individual e especializado para as dimensões que realmente serão usadas.

Pode não ser a resposta que esperava, mas é o que deveria fazer. Desenvolver software não é fazer o menor código, é fazer o melhor código que resolve o problema.

Comment: Não é difícil não, em aprendizado de máquina temos muito, estou com um com 6 dimensões por exemplo. Obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: É difícil, você citou 1 caso onde é usado. E um caso onde esta abstração não é desejada e o que eu falei para fazer funcionará muito melhor.