# Limpar string com Regex

Tags: php, regex

Tenho a seguinte array em PHP:

```
[
"Opcao 01 - Frase aleatória - Menu Superior",
"Opcao 02 - Outra Frase aleatória - Menu Su",
"Opcao 03 - Mais 01 Frase - Menu",
"Opcao 04 - Mais Frase -",
"Opcao 05 - Frase Simples",
]
```

Preciso limpar ela para ficar assim:

```
01 - Frase aleatória",
02 - Outra Frase aleatória",
03 - Mais 01 Frase",
04 - Mais Frase",
05 - Frase Simples",
```

E tenho que fazer isto com regex. Como seria a sequência para este filtro?

Comment: Já tentou isso sem aspas? "\d+\s+[-]\s+\w+\s+\d+"

Comment: Qual linguagem? você já tem algum contexto de codigo que não tem funcionado?

Comment: @Park olha eu acabei de tentar e não deu certo. Não traz nada de resposta. Até o \w deu certo mas depois ja da erro. Obrigado

Comment: @MartinsLuan vou usar no PHP.

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e informe melhor os critérios. Sempre será "Opção *número* - Item *número* - Menu Superior"? Os textos podem variar? etc

Comment: @hkotsubo feito amigo. Acho que melhorou agora. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o [seguinte](https://regex101.com/r/nxKvj3/1):

```
\d+\s+-[^-]*
```

Como você prefere sem os espaços, tente [isso](https://regex101.com/r/PY0B3F/1):

```
\d+\s+-[^-]*(?=\s)
```

Há outras formas de você fazer isso:

- **1)** \d+\s+-.*?(?=\s+-|$) [veja](https://regex101.com/r/HTOQnk/1)
- **2)** \d+\s+-(?:\s.*?(?=\s+-)|.+) [veja](https://regex101.com/r/ypsecc/1)
- **3)** (\d+\s+[-]\s+.*?(?=\s+-)|\d+\s+[-].*) [veja](https://regex101.com/r/3OlH2x/1)
- **4)** \d+\s+-(?:\s+\S*(?:\s(?!\s*-)\S*)*|.+) *mais eficiente que as outras*. *[Veja](https://regex101.com/r/BceQ1X/1)*

> A quarta opção é muito eficiente porque os pedaços até um espaço em
>   branco são combinados em "lotes", as verificações de um hífen são
>   feitas somente quando um espaço em branco é encontrado.

Comment: Cara deu certinho a unica coisa é que ele ta pegando o ultimo espaçõ antes do -. Tem como remover este espaço do final?

Comment: @Joao Nivaldo Dá sim, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Deu certinho agora. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) para fazer a substituição.

A regex pode ser algo como `^\w+ (\d+ -[^\-]+)( -.*)?$`:

- os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Isso garante que estou verificando toda a string.
- o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` significa "letras (de A a Z, maiúsculas ou minúsculas), números (de 0 a 9) ou o caractere `_`"
- o atalho `\d` significa "qualquer dígito de 0 a 9"
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências".
- `[^\-]` é "qualquer caractere que **não** seja hífen"
- `.*` é "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere", e o `?` logo depois torna o trecho `( -.*)` opcional (ou seja, pode ter um espaço, hífen e "qualquer coisa" no final da string)

Então a regex começa com `\w+` (uma ou mais ocorrências de letras, números ou `_`), seguido de espaço, depois um ou mais números (`\d+`), espaço, hífen, vários caracteres que não são hífen (isso garante que só vai pegar até o próximo hífen), seguidos opcionalmente por espaço, hífen e `.*` (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa), e por fim o final da string.

O trecho `\d+ -[^\-]+` está entre parênteses, e isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Isso quer dizer que o texto que corresponde a este trecho pode ser referenciado posteriormente.

No caso, como é o primeiro par de parênteses, o texto que for capturado estará disponível na variável especial `$1`, que posso usar no segundo parâmetro do `preg_replace`:

```
$textos = array(
  "Opcao 01 - Frase aleatória - Menu Superior",
  "Opcao 02 - Outra Frase aleatória - Menu Su",
  "Opcao 03 - Mais 01 Frase - Menu",
  "Opcao 04 - Mais Frase -",
  "Opcao 05 - Frase Simples");
foreach($textos as $texto) {
    echo preg_replace('/^\w+ (\d+ -[^\-]+)( -.*)?$/', '$1', $texto), PHP_EOL;
}
```

O resultado é:

> 01 - Frase aleatória
> 02 - Outra Frase aleatória
> 03 - Mais 01 Frase
> 04 - Mais Frase
> 05 - Frase Simples

---

Se quiser, pode passar o array inteiro para `preg_replace`, que o retorno será outro array com as substituições feitas:

```
$textos = array(
    "Opcao 01 - Frase aleatória - Menu Superior",
    "Opcao 02 - Outra Frase aleatória - Menu Su",
    "Opcao 03 - Mais 01 Frase - Menu",
    "Opcao 04 - Mais Frase -",
    "Opcao 05 - Frase Simples");
var_dump(preg_replace('/^\w+ (\d+ -[^\-]+)( -.*)?$/', '$1', $textos));
```

Saída:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "01 - Frase aleatória"
  [1]=>
  string(27) "02 - Outra Frase aleatória"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "03 - Mais 01 Frase"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "04 - Mais Frase"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "05 - Frase Simples"
}
```

---

#### Caracteres acentuados

Na regex acima, `\w` não considera caracteres acentuados, então se a string começar com "Opção", por exemplo, não funcionará. Outro detalhe é que `\w` também considera números e o caractere `_`. Se quiser somente letras, uma opção é usar as [propriedades Unicode](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) (usando a categoria `L` - que considera todas as letras, inclusive de outros alfabetos, como o japonês, coreano, cirílico, etc), não esquecendo de usar o [modificador](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `u` (logo depois da segunda `/` na regex):

```
// trocar \w por \p{L} e adicionar a opção "u" na regex, para considerar letras acentuadas 
var_dump(preg_replace('/^\p{L}+ (\d+ -[^\-]+)( -.*)?$/u', '$1', $textos));
```

Se quiser deixar o `\w`, basta adicionar a opção `u` (lembrando que o `\w` também considera números e o `_`):

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/^\w+ (\d+ -[^\-]+)( -.*)?$/u', '$1', $textos));
```

---

#### Espaços

As opções acima funcionam para quando há apenas um espaço separando as palavras, números e hífens.

Mas caso haja mais de um espaço separando essas partes, pode usar `\s+` (um ou mais espaços). Além disso, modifiquei um pouco a regex para o caso de ter mais de um espaço antes do segundo hífen (por exemplo, `"Opção 01 - Frase aleatória    - Menu Superior"`):

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/^\w+\s+(\d+\s+-\s+([^\-\s]+(\s+[^\-\s]+)*))(\s+-.*)?$/u', '$1', $textos));
```

Para o trecho entre os dois hífens, usei `[^\-\s]+(\s+[^\-\s]+)*`:

- `[^\-\s]+`: uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa que não seja hífen nem espaço
- `(\s+[^\-\s]+)*`: zero ou mais ocorrências de "espaços, seguido de vários caracteres que não sejam hífen ou espaço"

Com isso, eu capturo o texto `"Frase aleatória"`, sem o risco de pegar o segundo hífen, nem os espaços que tem antes dele (mas pegando os espaços entre as palavras). Pode parecer uma complicação extra, pois você pode pensar "*por que não usar `.*?` que é mais simples?*". O que me leva a outro tópico: a eficiência de uma regex.

---

#### Eficiência

Apenas para efeito de comparação com a [resposta do usuário @Park](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367170/112052) (**que também está certa**, não estou criticando, apenas comparando as soluções), a regex que sugeri é mais eficiente. O [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) possui uma ferramenta de *debugging* que é bem interessante para ver como a regex se comporta.

No caso da regex `(\d+\s+[-]\s+.*?(?=\s+-)|\d+\s+[-].*)`, veja que ela leva [entre 67 e 137 passos](https://regex101.com/r/a85hJm/8/debugger) (dependendo da string) para encontrar um *match*. Já a regex que sugeri [leva no máximo 21 passos](https://regex101.com/r/F2CRRu/2/debugger). A segunda versão, com `\s+` em vez de espaço, leva [no máximo 29 passos](https://regex101.com/r/BEpppr/1/debugger).

E caso a string não corresponda à regex, a que eu usei demora menos para perceber isso e reportar um *no-match* ([53 passos](https://regex101.com/r/F2CRRu/3/debugger) contra [149](https://regex101.com/r/0UVEXA/2/debugger) - a segunda versão, com `\s+`, também precisa de [53 passos](https://regex101.com/r/BEpppr/2/debugger)).

Dito isso, obviamente estes resultados são estimativas e os números exatos dependem de como a *engine* interna do PHP é implementada: tanto os links do [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) que coloquei acima quanto as funções `preg_xxx` usam uma *engine* [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), mas dependendo da regex e das strings utilizadas, algumas linguagens fazem otimizações internas em alguns casos, por exemplo. Mesmo usando o mesmo tipo de regex (PCRE), os números podem variar de uma linguagem/engine/ferramenta para outra.

Mas de qualquer forma os números reais não devem mudar muito. A regex da outra resposta usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) (o que sempre faz ela tentar todas as alternativas, até uma dar certo) e `.*?`, que faz a engine testar várias possibilidades (afinal, significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de **qualquer** caractere"), e isso faz com que ela execute vários passos adicionais (no caso de strings que não satisfazem a regex, ela precisa testar todas as possibilidades até ter certeza de que não dá mesmo).

A minha regex até usa `.*`, mas é no final da string e dentro de um bloco opcional, o que reduz um pouco este [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052), além de não ter alternância (uma única alternativa a se testar em vez de duas) e usar `[^\-]` (qualquer caractere que não seja hífen), que gera menos possibilidades do que o `.` (que é "qualquer caractere", o que [aumenta exponencialmente as possibilidades](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), já que o próprio hífen [pode ser incluído se a regex achar necessário](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazytrap)).

O fato de eu ter usado `^` e `$` também ajuda nesse sentido, pois sem eles a regex é testada novamente a cada posição da string, até encontrar o ponto em que ela é satisfeita. Usando `^` elimina esses passos a mais, pois ela já sabe que deve sempre buscar do início da string. Ou seja, vários detalhes que isoladamente parecem "bobos", mas juntos fazem diferença.

**É claro** que para uma quantidade pequena de strings curtas, a diferença será insignificante (provavelmente será de milissegundos ou até menos), mas se for lidar com uma grande quantidade de dados, pode ser que faça diferença. Inclusive, usar `.*` pode causar um aumento exponencial de passos, dependendo do caso (aumentar 3 caracteres na string inválida, por exemplo, [só adiciona mais 3 passos](https://regex101.com/r/F2CRRu/5/debugger) na minha regex (de 53 para 56, inclusive [na segunda versão com `\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/BEpppr/3/debugger)), enquanto na outra [adiciona 15](https://regex101.com/r/a85hJm/6/debugger) (pula de 149 para 164)).

Não sei se você vai lidar com uma quantidade tão grande de dados a ponto de fazer alguma diferença no desempenho, mas de qualquer forma fica registrada a alternativa.

Comment: Vc sempre me surpreendendo com regex. Daria mais de um upvote se fosse possível! Kk

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa usar a função chamada str_replace, fiz um exemplo pra você

```
<?php    
function limpar_stringl($string){ // replace para limpar variaveis Opcao 01 - Item 01 - Menu Superior
    $string = str_replace('Opcao','', $string);
    $string = str_replace(' - Menu Superior','', $string);
    return $string;
}
echo limpar_stringl("Opcao 01 - Item 01 - Menu Superior");
```

1. Sempre que quiser refatorar um novo caractere ou conjunto de caracteres palavras etc você vai precisar adicionar uma nova linha no codigo
2. Relacionar o item`$string = str_replace('caractere ou palavra','', $string);`

Comment: Eu preciso como disse fazer com o REGEX. Obrigado