# É melhor fazer uma requisição grande ao banco de dados ou várias pequenas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, cliente-servidor

O que é mais recomendável? Tenho um sistema web que no *load* da página ASPX ele alimenta vários controles com dados de várias tabelas do banco de dados. É melhor fazer uma pesquisa com uma requisição (*post*) em cada tabela do banco no servidor remoto ou em uma *query* só já retornar todos os dados de todas as tabelas alimentando um `DataSet` só? Ou seja, é melhor fazer mais requisições ao servidor e transportar menos dados na banda ou menos requisições e transportar mais dados na banda?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sempre dizemos para essas coisas que depende, mas no geral fazer uma requisição que retorne um grande volume de dados é melhor já que o custo de cada requisição em suas várias partes de transporte e processamento costuma ser bem considerável. O que é melhor sair da sala e ir na cozinha pegar uma bolacha de cada vez ou trazer o pacote todo?

Mas é claro que se você trouxer muita coisa e não precisar, não compensa. Tem caso que pra decidir o que vai trazer precisa trazer alguma coisa anterior. Pode ser que alguns casos o sistema de banco de dados pode se dar melhor com um volume menor e otimizar. E tem casos que você precisa começar mostrar alguns dados para o usuário antes de receber tudo para dar uma experiência melhor, mesmo que o todo tenha um custo maior. Percebe que há casos que é melhor trazer aos poucos? Mas isso é mais raro. Entenda que existem uma quantidade enorme de coisas para observar para definir o que compensa.

Quanto pior o transporte mais fácil é decidir por uma única requisição, em uma rede remota uma requisição tem uma vantagem enorme.

Por isso que sempre falo que aprender a receita de bolo do que deve fazer serve pra nada, o que importa é entender profundamente todo o funcionamento das tecnologias que estão envolvidas no que faz e tomar a decisão de acordo com a necessidade. É, eu sei, todos querem uma regra mágica que decide fácil tudo, mas isto não existe, e por muitos acreditarem que existe é que tem tanto software ruim.

A pergunta é ambígua, ora, transportar menos dados sempre é melhor, sempre! Mas tem que considerar a operação toda, não individual, me parece que está falando de fazer uma transação com um volume de dados ou várias outras com pouco volume mas que somando dá a mesma quantidade, então aí não faz sentido pelo custo adicional, inclusive de volume de dados de transporte porque em cada transporte tem um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi Maniero. Talvez não tenha me expressado detalhadamente, mas o que eu queria saber, você já esclareceu. No caso preciso trazer uma quantidade de dados já no carregar da página, pois ela precisa abrir com essas informações. E como esses dados vinham de várias tabelas diferentes, fiquei na dúvida em fazer uma requisição por tabela ou já buscar tudo em uma requisição só. nesta caso como estas informações fazem parte da página sem interação do usuário e não é muita coisa, é melhor em uma requisição só. Obrigado.