# Como usar o .replace() para remover strings em Python

Tags: python, string

Eu estou fazendo um exercício do Coursera em Python. Nesse exercício ele pede para construir uma função em Python que recebe uma string (palavra) e remove os símbolos de pontuação. Ele me fornece uma lista de strings `["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']` e coloca como sugestão de resolução para o problema usar o método `.replace()` para strings.

O problema é que a sintaxe do `.replace()` é composta da forma: `replace(old, new, count)`, onde os dois primeiros parâmetros são obrigatórios. Como resolver isso? No argumento `_old_` coloco `" "` como espaço vazio?

Answer (score 5):

A ideia é basicamente essa, mas é uma solução um pouco mais complicada que isso porque se trocar o símbolo por um espaço pode ser que fique dois espaços seguidos, o que seria errado, porém em alguns casos não terá um espaço em seguida e aí o espaço seria melhor porque juntar duas palavras será muito pior. O correto é fazer uma algoritmo um pouco mais sofisticado entendendo como trocar. Se fosse só esse padrão até seria mais simples, mas pode ter outros.

Como o exercício parece pedir só uma forma simples e só tem a intenção de de trocar um símbolo por um espaço então a solução que pensou de trocar o símbolo por um espaço é a adequada, mas deve colocar o espaço no parâmetro *new* que é o que ficará na conclusão. Algo assim:

```
texto = texto.replace('@', ' ')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DNOXIc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Replacepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Replace2.py).

Se quiser se arriscar, e vale como experimento é trocar os espaço por nada. O nada são duas aspas seguidas e sem o espaço, algo assim:

```
texto = texto.replace('!', '')
```

Você teria que fazer vários comandos desses, um para cada símbolo que for "limpar". Isso é extremamente ineficiente, mas para um exercício não tem problema.

Alguém provavelmente irá sugerir usar um RegEx no `replace()` para ficar mais sofisticado, mas parece avançado para o que está aprendendo agora, e como dizem:

> Quando você tenta resolver um problema com RegEx você passa ter dois problemas

Answer (score 5):

Olhando na [documentação do método `replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), é dito que:

> *Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new*

Ou seja, se você fizer `string.replace('alguma coisa', 'outra coisa')`, todas as ocorrências de `"alguma coisa"` serão substituídas por `"outra coisa"`. E se no lugar de "outra coisa" você passar a string vazia (`''` ou `""` - repare que não há nada entre as aspas), o `"alguma coisa"` é trocado por "nada", o que na prática é o mesmo que remover o trecho `"alguma coisa"`.

Sendo assim, se você deve obrigatoriamente usar **somente** `replace` e a lista de caracteres a serem removidos, não tem jeito, tem que remover um a um. Assim:

```
simbolos_pontuacao = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
texto = 'Lorem: "ipsum" \'dolor\', sit! Amet; bla... bl@ #etc#, whiskas sache!!'
# para cada símbolo, remove-o da string
for c in simbolos_pontuacao:
    texto = texto.replace(c, '')

print(texto) # Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet blabl etc whiskas sache
```

Não é lá muito eficiente porque cada chamada de `replace` cria uma nova string (por isso que eu preciso atribuir o retorno na variável `texto`).

Para quem gosta de uma "pegada" mais funcional, também dá para usar [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
texto = reduce(lambda t, s: t.replace(s, ''), simbolos_pontuacao, texto)
```

Que no fundo faz a mesma coisa que o *loop*, só que com mais [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052)...

Enfim, usando `replace`, não tem muito como fugir disso. Mas existem outras formas de fazer.

---

Outra forma é percorrer cada caractere da string e verificar se ela pertence à lista. Então eu junto todos que não pertencem e monto outra string:

```
texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in simbolos_pontuacao)
```

Também não deve ser muito eficiente porque para cada caractere da string eu tenho que percorrer toda a lista `simbolos_pontuacao` para verificar se o caractere é um dos que devem ser removidos (como [o operador `in` faz uma busca linear](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), a lista será percorrida várias vezes).

Uma alternativa é trocar a lista por um `set`, pois a busca em `set`'s é mais rápida se comparado a uma lista:

```
# usar set em vez de lista
simbolos_pontuacao = {"'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@'}
texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in simbolos_pontuacao)
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar regex. Como todos os símbolos da lista só tem um caractere, posso juntá-los em uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `['",.!:;#@]`. Assim, a substituição é feita de uma vez:

```
import re

r = re.compile(f'[{"".join(simbolos_pontuacao)}]')
texto = r.sub('', texto)
```

Se algum elemento da lista `simbolos_pontuacao` tivesse mais de um caractere, aí eu não poderia usar a classe de caracteres. Por exemplo, se tivesse `ab` na lista, então `[ab]` não serviria, pois isso significa "a letra `a` ou a letra `b`". Neste caso, eu tenho que usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
# incluí um elemento com mais de um caractere
simbolos_pontuacao = ['...', "'", '"', ",", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
texto = 'Lorem: "ipsum" \'dolor\', sit! Amet; bla... bl@ #etc#, whiskas sache!!'

import re

r = re.compile(f'({"|".join(map(re.escape, simbolos_pontuacao))})')
texto = r.sub('', texto)

print(texto) # Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet blabl etc whiskas sache
```

Neste caso a regex se tornou `(\.\.\.|'|"|,|!|:|;|\#|@)`. Repare que o ponto foi escrito como `\.`, já que ele possui significado especial em regex (significa "[qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://regular-expressions.info/dot.html)"), então para que ele corresponda a somente o caractere `.`, tenho que escapá-lo com `\`, e isso é feito por [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

No primeiro caso eu não precisei do escape porque os metacaracteres "perdem seus poderes" quando estão dentro de colchetes (nesse caso eu só precisaria escapar os próprios colchetes).

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Usando [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) é performático porém funciona apenas se as strings recebidas forem de apenas 1 caractere.

```
chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
texto = 'Lorem: "ipsum" \'dolor\', sit! Amet; bla... bl@ #etc#, whiskas sache!!'

resultado = texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', "".join(chars)))
# 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet bla bl etc whiskas sache'
```

---

### Explicação

Vou deixar aqui mais um método não abordado nas outras respostas ainda, que seria o método [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

O método [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) recebe uma "tabela de tradução" que deve ser um objeto que permita acesso indexado, como dicionários ou listas, onde o índice acessado é um inteiro representando o Unicode Code Point do caracterer (ver [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)) e o item acessado deve retornar o caractere substituto ou `None` para não incluir no resultado. Veja um exemplo de uso:

```
tabela = {
    ord("a"): "A",
    ord("b"): "*",
    ord("c"): None,
}
texto = "a-b-c-d"

print(texto.translate(tabela))    # 'A-*--d'
```

Estou montando esta tabela "na mão" para fins demonstrativos, mas geralmente se usa o método estático [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) para criá-la com mais facilidade. A mesma tabela acima poderia ser criada assim:

```
tabela = str.maketrans("ab", "A*", "c")
texto = "a-b-c-d"

print(texto.translate(tabela))  # 'A-*--d'
```

Explicando melhor o [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans), ele pode receber 1, 2 ou 3 argumentos:

- **1 argumento**: o argumento deve ser um dicionário (ou algum *mapping*) cujas chaves são inteiros (Unicode  Code Points) ou string com tamanho 1. Exemplo:

  ```py
  tabela = str.maketrans({
      97: 'A',  # ord('a') == 97
      'b': 66,  # ord('B') == 66
      'c': 'C',
      'd': None,
  })

  print(tabela)
  # {
  #     97: 'A', 
  #     98: 66, 
  #     99: 'C',
  #     100: None,
  # }
  ```
- **2 argumentos**: ambos devem ser strings e devem ter o mesmo tamanho. A tabela resultante mapeará chaves e valores com os mesmos índices nas strings. Exemplo:

  ```py
  tabela = str.maketrans('abcd', 'ABCD')

  print(tabela)
  # {
  #     97: 65, 
  #     98: 66, 
  #     99: 67,
  #     100: 68,
  # }
  ```
- **3 argumentos**: segue o mesmo padrão de 2 argumentos, porém o 3º argumento será uma string contendo os caracteres que devem ser mapeados para `None`. Exemplo:

  ```py
  tabela = str.maketrans('abc', 'ABC', 'd')

  print(tabela)
  # {
  #     97: 65, 
  #     98: 66, 
  #     99: 67,
  #     100: None,
  # }
  ```

Então bastaria usar a tabela criada pelo [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) no [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). Como ficaria em uma função:

```
def remove_chars(string, chars):
    return string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', "".join(chars)))
```

### Performance

Criei um [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-517080-6333) com 4 abordagens diferentes para o problema:

1. Usando [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

   ```py
   def remove_chars_translate(string, chars):
       return string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', "".join(chars)))
   ```
2. Usando *[generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?#generator-expressions)* como mencionado em outra resposta:

   ```py
    def remove_chars_gen_comprehension(string, chars):
        return "".join(c for c in string if c not in chars)
   ```
3. Mesma anterior, porém usando `set` para pesquisar caracteres:

   ```py
    def remove_chars_gen_comprehension_with_set(string, chars):
        chars = set(chars)
        return "".join(c for c in string if c not in chars)
   ```
4. Usando regex (também extraída da outra resposta):

   ```py
    def remove_chars_regex(string, chars):
        r = re.compile(f'({"|".join(map(re.escape, chars))})')
        return r.sub('', texto)
   ```

Os resultados na minha máquina (com 1_000_000 iterações) foram:

```
                  remove_chars_translate:  1.6842 s
          remove_chars_gen_comprehension: 11.0966 s
 remove_chars_gen_comprehension_with_set:  4.2422 s
                      remove_chars_regex:  5.9396 s
```

***Obs.**: Diminuí o número de iterações do `timeit` no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-517080-6333) pra não demorar muito para ter resultados (tinham resultados passando dos 30s).*

Comment: Muito bom, confesso que sempre tive preguiça de entender como o `maketrans` funciona, e finalmente entendi :-) E também fiquei surpreso que a regex não foi a mais lenta de todas (pelo jeito verificar se cada caractere está na lista acaba sendo pior do que imaginei, e o custo de criar um `set` acaba se pagando)

Comment: Eu criei a resposta achando que o `translate` valesse a pena pela implementação em C e por aparentemente fazer tudo num loop só... Mas o ganho com `set` também me pegou de surpresa.. não esperava tanto

Answer (score -1):

O Replace funciona como vai percorrer sua string buscando por ocorrência do valor passado no parâmetro `old`, e quando ele encontra esse valor na string, substitui pelo valor passado no segundo parâmetro.

O parâmetro `count` representa quantos ocorrências você quer que seja substituída na string, suponde que você tenha mais de uma ocorrência do valor pesquisado.

```py
texto = 'Hello World';

texto.replace('llo', 'troquei');

#Hetroquei World

texto.replace('l','L', 2);

#HeLLo World
```

Comment: Isso eu já sabia, mas como eu faço para remover uma string usando esse método, sem colocar nada no lugar?

Comment: para remover a parte da string é só substituir por string vazia por exemplo ```'Hello Word'.replace('llo','')``` vai retornar ```He Word```