# Por que Python tem números tão grandes?

Tags: python, tipagem, números

Qual seria o maior número em python? Python mostra o resultado de expressões como:

```
>>> 8**150000
```

O resultado teve 135465 dígitos! Queria saber a linguagem consegue fazer isso.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2bbbvk/how_does_python_handle_bignum_arithmetic/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python é uma linguagem de *script*, portanto o que importa para ela é ser fácil, é entregar o que o programador pede sem criar dificuldades. Não importa eficiência ou qualquer outro aspecto.

O computador precisa de espaço determinado para representar tipos porque a memória é um local de armazenamento com espaço delimitado. É física, para poder colocar algo em algum lugar precisa saber o tamanho a ser reservado.

Para ser eficiente uma linguagem precisa ter tipos que ocupam pouco espaço porque grande parte das operações exigem bem pouco. Ao mesmo tempo precisa ter tipos diferentes que ocupam muito espaço porque algumas operações precisam de dados muito grandes.

Quando a eficiência não importa, uma das técnicas possíveis é só ter um tipo que ocupa muito espaço podendo armazenar grandes números, mesmo que não use na maioria das vezes.

Mas por mais que você reserve espaço ainda pode faltar em certas situações, e a reserva de algo muito grande pode inviabilizar o uso, não só tornar ineficiente. Então precisa de uma outra técnica que aceite números pequenos e grandes de forma flexível, elástico.

Da mesma forma que Python criou uma infraestrutura para lidar com [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) que podem ter dados de tipos diferentes (tamanhos arbitrários), apesar disso não ser possível de forma direta no computador, a linguagem também criou uma forma do número aceitar tamanhos arbitrários. Há um mecanismo que controla isso e vai aumentando o tamanho do número possível conforme vai tendo necessidade. Obviamente que isso tem um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) de memória e de processamento, mas não importa para a linguagem. Isso se dá com alguma forma de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Enquanto em muitas linguagens a tipagem é eficiente e simples, igual ao que o computador precisa, obrigando o programador lidar com o tipo certo de acordo com o que precisa, em Python tem algo complexo internamente para facilitar a vida do programador.

Na verdade as outras linguagens costumam ter em sua biblioteca uma infra semelhante para lidar com números de tamanho arbitrários, mas você só usa se precisar, em Python você paga o preço dele sempre.

## Mecanismo

A técnica mais usada para obter isso é semelhante de um *array*, ou uma *string*, que não deixa de ser um *array*. O número é decomposto em partes, então cada elemento do *array* vai sendo uma das partes.

Vamos dizer que a estrutura interna fosse um *array* de bytes (pode usar algo maior para mais eficiência, eu usaria um `long` ou talvez um `int` mas provavelmente não), até 256 inteiros precisa só de 1 byte (mais o custo extra para controlar o tamanho e possivelmente outras questões), se for até 65536 precisa de 2 bytes, até cerca de 16 milhões precisa de 3 bytes, e 4 bilhões precisa de 4, e por volta de 1 trilhão precisa de 5, e assim por diante. E vai lidar se tem sinal, sem tem parte decimal e quantas.

Todas operações matemáticas consideram essa construção complexa e olha tudo isso quando faz a conta.

Deve imaginar que se o número mudar e o seu tamanho, também é necessário copiar ele para outro lugar para caber o novo número, mas como há uma indireção, o acesso é feito normalmente sem dificuldades, apenas tem um processamento a mais.

## Conclusão

Um dos segredos da programação é criar abstrações em cima de coisas complexas. Você usa o simples enquanto tem todo um maquinário por baixo do capô. Nada de errado nisso em certos cenários, mas quando a pessoa não entende essas coisas acaba-se criando uma horda de pseudo programadores, que não é um problema para a maior base de usuários de Python.

Se tiver interesse pode ver o [código fonte que cuida disso tudo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).