# Como capturar várias exceções com switch em C#?

Tags: c#, exceção, switch

Quero capturar algumas exceções usando `try-catch` e `switch`. Fiz algumas tentativas, mas não deu certo. Por exemplo:

```
    try 
    {
       //tarefas...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       switch ()
       {
         case PrimeiraExceção;
           tratar_a_exceção ...;
         break;

         case SegundaExceção;
           tratar_a_exceção ...;
         break;
           .
           .
           . 
       }
    }
```

Comment: faz vários catch: `Catch(ExceptionA){ } Catch(ExceptionB) { } ...`  e assim por diante

Comment: Valeu Ricardo! Não tem como fazer com switch será?

Comment: vc só pode ter um exception por Catch, não adiantar fazer swith pq vai ser sempre 1. O que pode acontecer é um exception devolver códigos de erro, ai pode fazer switch nos códigos

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, blz. Muito obrigada!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` não serve para capturar exceção, o `catch` serve para isto.

Se você tem uma ação para cada exceção capturada então basta usar vários `catch`es. Eles funcionam de forma análoga ao `switch` e será executado o bloco da qual exceção foi lançada.

Se as exceções seguintes foram mais gerais que as anteriores então mais que um `catch` pode ser executado já que ainda pode ter o que fazer em um contexto mais amplo, o contrário não funciona, já que se você tratar primeiro o mais geral o mais específico estará tratado junto.

Pode tratar uma exceção entre muitas também (somente uma é executada) se elas não tiverem relação direta, exemplo:

```
} catch (SenhaNaoNumericaException) {
    WriteLine("A senha não é numérica");
} catch (SenhaMuitoPequenaException) {
    WriteLine("Senha não numérica.");
} catch (SenhaInicioAbaixoDe4Exception) {
    WriteLine("Não pode começar com número abaixo de 4.");
} catch (SenhaSemCaractereEspecialException) {
    WriteLine("Não foi encontrado nenhum caractere especial");
}
```

Se deseja capturar uma exceção mais geral e tratar de forma diferente certas especificidades da exceção então precisa usar o mecanismo um pouco diferente. Vou reproduzir uma [resposta dada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31542237/221800) usando tradutor automático :D:

Se você puder atualizar seu aplicativo para C# 6, está com sorte. Esta versão C# implementou filtros de exceção. Então você pode escrever isto:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is CommunicationException || ex is SystemException) {
     //lidar com isso
}
```

Algumas pessoas pensam que este código é o mesmo que

```
catch (Exception ex) {
     if (ex is CommunicationException || ex is SystemException) {
         //lidar com isso
     }
     throw;
}
```

Mas não é. Na verdade, este é o único novo recurso do C# 6 que não é possível emular nas versões anteriores. Primeiro, um re-lançamento significa mais [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) do que pular o `catch`. Em segundo lugar, não é semanticamente equivalente. O novo recurso preserva a pilha intacta quando você está depurando seu código. Sem esse recurso, o *dump* de memória é menos útil ou até mesmo inútil.

[Um exemplo que mostra a diferença](http://www.volatileread.com/Wiki/Index?id=1087).

Outro exemplo:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException || 
                           ex is UnauthorizedAccessException || 
                           ex is NotSupportedException || 
                           ex is SecurityException || 
                           ex is DirectoryNotFoundException || 
                           ex is PathTooLongException) {
    WriteLine("deu erro");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/MultipleCatches.cs).

Assim cai no mesmo `catch` em todas essas exceções mas não em outras. Ouras condições podem ser usadas, não precisa ser só exceções, é como se fosse um `if` mesmo, mas é algo melhor.

Leia também: [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). E ainda: [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101). Em geral as pessoas usam exceções de forma equivocada, sugiro dar uma boa pesquisada aqui antes de usá-las. Pode começar [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D).

Comment: Opa, maravilha!! Ajudou bastante, muito obrigada @Maniero!