# Como saber se a diferença entre duas datas é maior que determinado valor?

Tags: php, datetime

Preciso fazer uma análise na diferença entre dois horários, passando isso no parâmetro de uma estrutura condicional.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 
$inicio = '08:37:09';
 
// Cria um objeto DateTime para o dia e hora atual.
$fim = new DateTime();
 
// Converte para um objeto DateTime do PHP
$inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $inicio);

//diferença entre os dois horários
$intervalo = $inicio->diff($fim);

//média a ser tomada como referência
$media = '00:10:00';

$mediaf = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $media);
```

Como eu poderia fazer uma estrutura de condição para avaliar se foi abaixo ou acima do tempo médio?

Como fiz até o momento:

```
if($intervalo->format('%H:%I:%S') > $mediaf){
    echo "atrasado";

}
```

Comment: Se houver algo a ser melhorado na pergunta, peço que se puderem, auxiliem-me nesta etapa, estou aberto a sugestões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está confundindo datas e horas com durações. Considere essas duas frases:

- O filme começa às duas horas da tarde
- O filme durou duas horas

Na primeira, "*duas horas*" refere-se a um horário: a um momento específico do dia. Na segunda, "*duas horas*" refere-se à duração: a quantidade de tempo, sem relação com um horário específico (não diz que horas começou nem terminou, só diz quanto tempo dura).

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras ("horas", "minutos", etc), e até mesmo a mesma notação (um relógio pode mostrar "00:10:00" para indicar que é meia-noite e dez, um cronômetro pode mostrar "00:10:00" para indicar que já se passaram 10 minutos), mas são conceitos diferentes: uma data representa um ponto específico de um calendário (dia, mês e ano), e um horário representa um momento específico de um dia. Já uma duração é apenas uma quantidade de tempo, e não está associada com um instante específico.

---

No caso do PHP, um `DateTime` representa uma data e hora. Já uma duração (quantidade de tempo) é representada por um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). Inclusive, se olharmos a [documentação do método `diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), veremos que ele retorna um `DateInterval`.

E no fim você usa o [método `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), que retorna uma string, e compara com um `DateTime`, que é uma data. Não faz sentido. Aliás, a variável `$media` me parece representar uma duração de 10 minutos, então também não faz sentido transformá-la em uma data.

Outro detalhe é que a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) diz o seguinte: "*DateInterval instances are [incomparable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.incomparable)*" - ou seja, não tem como comparar um `DateInterval` com outro.

Por isso o jeito é fazer tudo manualmente. Uma solução seria usar o `getTimestamp()` das datas (que retorna o [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) - total de segundos desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) e subtrair um do outro, assim você obtém o total de segundos entre as duas datas.

Depois converta a duração de 10 minutos para segundos, e compare esses valores:

```php
// $inicio e $fim da mesma forma que vc fez...

// diferença entre os dois horários (em segundos)
$intervalo = $fim->getTimestamp() - $inicio->getTimestamp();

// duração de 10 minutos
$media = '00:10:00';
// calcula o total de segundos da duração
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $media);
$total_segundos = ($h * 3600) + ($m * 60) + $s;

if ($intervalo> $total_segundos) {
    echo "atrasado";
}
```

---

Se bem que neste caso não precisaria usar `DateTime`, me parece um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052) desnecessário. Você pode usar [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime) para converter o horário inicial em um timestamp, e [`time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time) para obter o timestamp atual:

```php
$inicio = strtotime('08:37:09');
$fim = time();

$intervalo = $fim - $inicio;

// duração de 10 minutos
$media = '00:10:00';
// calcula o total de segundos da duração
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $media);
$total_segundos = ($h * 3600) + ($m * 60) + $s;

if ($intervalo> $total_segundos) {
    echo "atrasado";
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! que hajam mais usuários como você! Obrigado novamente!