# Como um programa é carregado na memória e depois executado?

Tags: memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, arquitetura-computadores

Imagine que eu escrevi um "hello world" em linguagem C. Compilei e gerei um executável, depois o executei.

O resultado da compilação é um binário, que na verdade também é um conjunto de instruções que serão executadas pelo processador, correto?

Após o comando de execução, como os binários são transferidos para a memória RAM?

Após os binários estarem em memória, o sistema operacional faz uma chamada em *assembler* pedindo para o processador executar as instruções do binário, se sim é o sistema operacional que fornece o endereço de memoria das instruções?

Comment: Seu fluxo tá um pouco torto. Mas, independente disto, as instruções são executadas uma após a outra, quem tem o trabalho de "saber" qual o endereço da próxima instrução é o processador e não o SO.

Comment: Torto como assim?, eu sei que as instruções são executadas sequencialmente. Oque eu gostaria de saber é como o processador sabe que deve executar instruções a partir da posição de memoria "x"?, alguém deve pedir pra ele fazer isso, não seria o S.O?, imagino que sim pois após o comando de execução o fluxo passa pelo kernel do S.O antes de ir para processador.

Comment: Ele sabe isso porque tem um registrador que está sempre apontando pra posição de memória que está a próxima instrução.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acho que vai querer saber [como o computador trabalha com o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

A maneira exata de como o sistema operacional carrega um executável despende d e qual sistema operacional estamos falando. O próprio formato do executável também depende.

## Memória virtual

Nos SOs modernos existe um sistema de memória virtual. Quando um comando manda carregar um executável normalmente ele mapeia o arquivo para a memória. Então de certa forma não importa muito o que está no sistema de armazenamento de massa ou na memória RAM. Claro que precisa estar na RAM para executar, mas quando o conteúdo irá para a RAM é determinado pela necessidade e algoritmos implementados no sistema operacional. A carga é feita em páginas com tamanho 4KB (o mais comum).

[image: Memória virtual]

Os endereços virtuais são fornecidos pelo sistema operacional. Os endereços reais são fornecidos pelo processador. Todo processador moderno de alta capacidade possui um subsistema de tradução de endereços virtuais para físicos que não impõe custo ao processamento normal.

Tudo isso pode ser melhor visto em [outra pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203928/101).

## Transferência

A cópia é feita por outro serviço do sistema operacional que interage com o sistema de arquivos e o *driver* que entende como comandar o sistema de disco ou outra forma de armazenamento "permanente". Obviamente que ele depende da colaboração do processador principal ou algum secundário que faz o controle dos dispositivos de entrada e saída e a memória ([DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)).

Quando a carga é feita é possível ir entregando as instruções para o processador.

## Relocação

A carga normalmente implica em acerto de endereços diversos de símbolos globais. O código trabalha com endereços relativos. Ele não sabe bem onde ele estará de fato na memória. Sabendo os endereços relativos pode-se obter o absoluto de todos símbolos e o SO é o responsável por relocar os endereços.

## Carga do executável

Claro que o executável não tem só instruções. Existem uma série de informações que ajudam o sistema operacional decidir como trabalhar com aquilo, que configura como ele precisará trabalhar, entre outras coisas.

Existem dados estáticos. O exemplo mais comum são os textos (*strings*) presentes código. Mas na verdade praticamente qualquer literal estará de alguma forma ou junto às instruções ou na área estática.

Podem existir também dados que não são acessados diretamente mas que são necessários para a aplicação. Na verdade dá pra enfiar qualquer coisa no executável :)

Antes de iniciar a execução é reservado uma área de memória para a [*stack* e o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) começa ser formado, se necessário, quase sempre é. Mas isso tem mais a ver com o processo como um todo, até porque cada *thread* nova terá seu próprio *stack*.

## Conclusão

Enfim, simplificadamente é isso. Dá pra escrever um livro sobre o assunto. Novas perguntas específicas podem ser feitas.

Se deseja informações sobre o funcionamento eletrônico da transferência, aqui não é o local mais adequado. Se deseja algo mais detalhado, precisaria ver o que e em que SO.

## Adendo

O termo assembler é frequentemente mal usado. Na verdade, ali não era nem para usar [Assembler, nem Assembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101), é código de máquina mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pelo explicação, os links também ajudaram muito. Estou lendo o "Organização e Projeto de Computadores: A Interface Hardware/Software (David A. Patterson)". Ele tem me ajudado a entender esses conceitos, você recomenda alguma outra leitura para quem deseja se aprofundar no assunto ?.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, basicamente o executável é carregado à memória pelo Sistema Operacional. Na verdade, sua pergunta tem a ver com o gerenciamento de memória e cada sistema operacional tem uma forma de gerenciá-la.

Em termos gerais, é separado para o programa, uma região de memória que será usada pelo mesmo e a forma de uso será determinada pelo compilador (ou pela forma que o programa foi escrito). Essa alocação pode ser totalmente estática ou dinâmica (se o programa usar alocação dinâmica de memória). Quando o programa está em memória (arquitetura de Von Neumann), basicamente ele acessa diretamente as rotinas, processos e registradores através de ciclos de processamento (controlado diretamente pelo processador)

Sim, o SO fornece várias "células" de memória para o programa (que será endereçado usando técnicas de gerenciamento de memória).
Ou seja, é o SO que faz o gerenciamento de memória, controlando as alocações, protegendo, limpando e controlando o acesso de programas à memória principal.
Espero ter ajudado.